# How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, string-conversion

Can I convert a string representing a boolean value (e.g., 'true', 'false') into an intrinsic type in JavaScript?

I have a hidden form in HTML that is updated based on a user's selection within a list. This form contains some fields which represent boolean values and are dynamically populated with an intrinsic boolean value. However, once this value is placed into the hidden input field it becomes a string.

The only way I could find to determine the field's boolean value, once it was converted into a string, was to depend upon the literal value of its string representation.

```
var myValue = document.myForm.IS_TRUE.value;
var isTrueSet = myValue == 'true';
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just to highlight an odd example of avoiding triple-equals comparison: I have a function `currentSortDirection()` that returns `1` for an ascending sort, `0` for a descending sort, and `-1` for not set. Using `while (currentSortDirection() != desiredSortDirection) { sortColumn() }` works great, since `-1 != true` **and** `-1 != false`...but changing this to `while (Boolean(currentSortDirection) !== ...) {...}` forces `-1` into a `true`, necessitating an additional couple of lines of prep, just to make jshint happy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965

Comment: @Droogans: What happens if `desiredSortDirection` is set to `asc`? I know in a controlled environment you are probably in control over the value `desiredSortDirection` is set to but in a shared environment when the input of `desiredSortDirection` can come from anywhere in any form, type-checking against custom objects and defensive programming can save a lot of hours of debugging. Your code is absolutely fine and nothing is wrong with it, I'm merely pointing out that there is no one-fit-all answer/solution and it will always be scenario dependant.

Comment: "Is there a better way to accomplish this?" - there is certainly a worse way :D `string=(string==String(string?true:false))?(string?true:false):(!string?true:fa‌​lse);`

Comment: Easily handle strings and bools: `function parseBool(val) { return val === true || val === "true" }`

Comment: @Mark `function checkBool(x) { if(x) {return true;} else {return false;} }`

Comment: @Sebi: You forgot to document it: `if (checkBool(x) != false) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: `!!(parseInt(value) || value === "true")`

Comment: You can't, it is impossible!

Comment: Just a note. I am always amazed by Javascript expression parsing rule-set, for example, `123+44+'2'+1` gives `"16721"`. Every + after '2' is interpreted as concatenation operation, wow :-D. While PHP gives 170 as an answer, which is more transparent, because in PHP plus is not ambiguous - it is just used for arithmetic operations. Concatenation operation is performed with different operator

Comment: I haven't found an answer which solves undefined+string combination properly. So eventually I wrote one-liner for this:
`const StrToBool = (value) => !!value && value !== "false" && parseInt(value) !== 0;` 
This one liner gives following results:
`StrToBool(undefined) => false,
StrToBool('true') => true,
StrToBool('false') => false,
StrToBool('0') => false,
StrToBool('Whatever') => true,
StrToBool('1') => true`

Comment: `!myVar.slice(4,5);`

`myVar = 'TRUE' // true`
`myVar = 'FALSE' // false`

Comment: @AndrewLuca 's answer is great - it handles undefined, null and all other types. It considers non-zero numbers as true as well as the string 'true'. And all in a concise way.

Comment: `toBool ={'false':false,'true':true }
invertBool = {'false':true,'true':false}`

can be used 
`toBool[string]`

Comment: JSON.parse('true') is the most easiest way to convert to boolean

Comment: 'true' === true is false

Comment: I recently had a similar issue. I used a data attribute on an element with a true or false string. At a certain interaction I wanted to toggle the string.
I came up with this:
`boolString = (!(/true/).test(boolString)).toString()`
It makes a direct string check if the string is "true". If not, it assumes "false" no matter what. Then it negates it, and makes it into a string.

Comment: exactly is my problem my man, you're a gem to ask this

Answer (score 4973, accepted):

## Do:

```
var isTrueSet = (myValue === 'true');
```

using the identity operator (`===`), which doesn't make any implicit type conversions when the compared variables have different types.

This will set `isTrueSet` to a boolean `true` if the string is "true" and boolean `false` if it is string "false" or not set at all.

For making it case-insensitive, try:

```
var isTrueSet = /^true$/i.test(myValue);
// or
var isTrueSet = (myValue?.toLowerCase?.() === 'true');
// or
var isTrueSet = (String(myValue).toLowerCase() === 'true');
```

---

### Don't:

You should probably **be cautious about using these two methods** for your specific needs:

```
var myBool = Boolean("false");  // == true

var myBool = !!"false";  // == true
```

Any string which isn't the empty string will evaluate to `true` by using them. Although they're the cleanest methods I can think of concerning to boolean conversion, I think they're not what you're looking for.

Comment: `myValue === 'true';` is precisely equivalent to `myValue == 'true';`. There is no benefit in using `===` over `==` here.

Comment: I follow [Crockford's advice](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and use `===` and `!==` whenever it makes sense, which is almost always.

Comment: @guinaps most of the javascript strict conventions to blanket apply to all javascript usage just cause convoluted code and a lack of understanding of the principles, theory, or usage of javascript.

Comment: `===` should be used because it's also checking for the right type. Also, it has better comparison performances than `==`.

Comment: This doesn't account for 'false'...if the string isn't 'true' or 'false', then myBool should probably be undefined. eg let myBool = (myValue === 'true')?true:(myValue === 'false')?false:undefined;

Comment: I would instead use `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`. It would allow you to use methods like `parseInt()` and compare it's value using `if(parseInt(booleanVariable))`

Comment: Thanks. Comes in handy when the value comes from an environment variable, which are strings JavaScript, and need to translate those into booleans.

Comment: This does account for `false` as if the string doesn't match or is undefined then the conditional will evaluate to boolean `false`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Better put it in a utility 

`export function BoolFromString(value: 'true' | 'false' | string) {
  return (String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true');
}
`

Answer (score 861):

## Warning

This highly upvoted legacy answer is technically correct but only covers a very specific scenario, when your string value is EXACTLY `"true"` or `"false"`.

An invalid json string passed into these functions below **WILL throw an exception**.

---

**Original answer:**

How about?

```
JSON.parse("True".toLowerCase());
```

or with jQuery

```
$.parseJSON("TRUE".toLowerCase());
```

Comment: The problem with this is that many potential value generate a parse error which stops JS execution. So running JSON.parse("FALSE") bombs Javascript. The point of the question, I think, is not to simply solve these exact cases, but also be resilient to other cases.

Comment: It's pretty simple to just say `JSON.parse("TRUE".toLowerCase())` so that it can parse correctly.

Comment: @BishopZ : Stopping JS execution is probably a desirable feature following best-pattern coding styles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast

Comment: If we go by question title alone it goes out of discussion all that JSON thing. The question was about a string not about what can result from its transformation. Of course looking at an object "stored" in a string using the JSON format one can ask what happens in such a scenario. Or we could go as well another way towards strings converted in numbers (not into objects) for example ```let x = 0 + "-0" // "0-0"``` versus ```let x = 0 - "-0" // 0``` but, again, we move out of main topic :)

Comment: Careful with `JSON.parse` as it is one of the source of DOM-based client-side JSON injection. https://portswigger.net/web-security/dom-based/client-side-json-injection

Comment: @RaviMCA Couldn't you have come up with something a little more fact-based than that link? You may be right (though just yesterday I was reading about the difference between `eval` and `JSON.parse`, and how you use the latter to avoid the injection problems of the former) but that page is nothing more than poorly described hearsay.

Answer (score 298):

```
const stringToBoolean = (stringValue) => {
    switch(stringValue?.toLowerCase()?.trim()){
        case "true": 
        case "yes": 
        case "1": 
          return true;

        case "false": 
        case "no": 
        case "0": 
        case null: 
        case undefined:
          return false;

        default: 
          return JSON.parse(stringValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it can be simplified. 1) There is no need to test for `"true"`, `"yes"` and `"1"`. 2) `toLowerCase` does not return `null`. 3) `Boolean(string)` is the same as `string!==""` here. => `switch(string.toLowerCase()) {case "false": case "no": case "0": case "": return false; default: return true;}`

Comment: Note, this will default to `true` - for example: `stringToBoolean('banana') // true`

Comment: The result of JSON.parse(stringValue) will be of return type "number" instead of a "boolean" if you input a number. Otherwise fine. Your function's name is stringToBoolean, not stringToNumberOrBooleanOrError. Also, if you pass undefined, you get a JSON.parse error, which is (might be) fine, but lets the programmer at a loss as to where the error is (if there's no stacktrace...).

Comment: I think the question is asking about only converting the string 'true' -> true (native type) and 'false' -> false (native type).

But, if you want to do a truthy/falsey conversion are you are here, you could just add `!!` to the front: `const convertedVar = !!'myString' // is true`

Answer (score 271):

I think this is much more universal:

`if (String(a).toLowerCase() == "true")` ...

It goes:

```
String(true) == "true"     //returns true
String(false) == "true"    //returns false
String("true") == "true"   //returns true
String("false") == "true"  //returns false
```

Comment: When you can receive a string in uppercase or a boolean, then `String(a).toLowerCase() === 'true'`

Answer (score 171):

Remember to match case:

```
var isTrueSet = (myValue.toLowerCase() === 'true');
```

Also, if it's a form element checkbox, you can also detect if the checkbox is checked:

```
var isTrueSet = document.myForm.IS_TRUE.checked;
```

Assuming that if it is checked, it is "set" equal to true. This evaluates as true/false.

Comment: This will fail if myValue is null or undefined or any type other than a string.

Answer (score 161):

This is the easiest way to do boolean conversion I came across recently. Thought of adding it.

```
JSON.parse('true');
```

```js
let trueResponse = JSON.parse('true');

let falseResponse = JSON.parse('false');

console.log(trueResponse);
console.log(falseResponse);
```

Comment: This works, but you have to be careful not to pass it empty strings or it'll pop.

Comment: the sexy solution, I liked it!

Comment: take all my money! 

Comment: This is a quick and dirty solution for storing true/false inside [.env](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Comment: should wrap in try/catch in many cases

Comment: The best. I'm using it in an input type of radio, so the value is never an empty string

Answer (score 138):

You can use regular expressions:

```
/*
 * Converts a string to a bool.
 *
 * This conversion will:
 *
 *  - match 'true', 'on', or '1' as true.
 *  - ignore all white-space padding
 *  - ignore capitalization (case).
 *
 * '  tRue  ','ON', and '1   ' will all evaluate as true.
 *
 */
function strToBool(s)
{
    // will match one and only one of the string 'true','1', or 'on' regardless
    // of capitalization and regardless of surrounding white-space.
    //
    regex=/^\s*(true|1|on)\s*$/i

    return regex.test(s);
}
```

If you like extending the String class you can do:

```
String.prototype.bool = function() {
    return strToBool(this);
};

alert("true".bool());
```

For those (see the comments) that would like to extend the String object to get this but are worried about enumerability and are worried about clashing with other code that extends the String object:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "com_example_bool", {
    get : function() {
        return (/^(true|1)$/i).test(this);
    }
});
alert("true".com_example_bool);
```

(Won't work in older browsers of course and Firefox shows false while Opera, Chrome, Safari and IE show true. [Bug 720760](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720760))

Comment: You can always prefix the function if you're afraid that it'll interfere with some other code. If some code still breaks, that code is just too brittle and should be fixed. If your added function makes the object too heavy where it cause a performance issue for other code, then, obviously you don't want to do that. But, I don't think it's generally a bad idea to extend built-in objects. They also wouldn't be publicly extendable if that was the case.

Comment: @DTrejo @Szymon I disagree. This is exactly the kind of thing overloading the prototype is for. If you're afraid of it breaking (poor) code that relies on for..in, there are ways to hide properties from enumeration. See `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: I love the simplicity of the regex approach to check for values that are typically "true". A suggestion for modification: the logic of false is `0` and true is non-zero. Therefore I think it's better to check for the opposite of false, i.e. `return !(/^(false|0|off|no)$/i).test(this);` -- also notice that I included "no".

Comment: Most of this answer is actually not very performant. If you _can_ make any assumptions about your input, such as the input never being "on" or "tRUe", then it would pay to not overengineer your implementation. Extending `String.prototype` is never okay.

Answer (score 85):

Wood-eye be careful.
After seeing the consequences after applying the top answer with 500+ upvotes, I feel obligated to post something that is actually useful:

Let's start with the shortest, but very strict way:

```
var str = "true";
var mybool = JSON.parse(str);
```

And end with a proper, more tolerant way:

```
var parseBool = function(str, strict) 
{
    // console.log(typeof str);
    // strict: JSON.parse(str)
    
    if (str == null)
    {
        if (strict)
            throw new Error("Parameter 'str' is null or undefined.");

        return false;
    }
    
    if (typeof str === 'boolean')
    {
        return (str === true);
    } 
    
    if(typeof str === 'string')
    {
        if(str == "")
            return false;
            
        str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if(str.toLowerCase() == 'true' || str.toLowerCase() == 'yes')
            return true;
        
        str = str.replace(/,/g, '.');
        str = str.replace(/^\s*\-\s*/g, '-');
    }
    
    // var isNum = string.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
    // var isNum = /^\d+$/.test(str);
    if(!isNaN(str))
        return (parseFloat(str) != 0);
        
    return false;
}
```

Testing:

```
var array_1 = new Array(true, 1, "1",-1, "-1", " - 1", "true", "TrUe", "  true  ", "  TrUe", 1/0, "1.5", "1,5", 1.5, 5, -3, -0.1, 0.1, " - 0.1", Infinity, "Infinity", -Infinity, "-Infinity"," - Infinity", " yEs");

var array_2 = new Array(null, "", false, "false", "   false   ", " f alse", "FaLsE", 0, "00", "1/0", 0.0, "0.0", "0,0", "100a", "1 00", " 0 ", 0.0, "0.0", -0.0, "-0.0", " -1a ", "abc");


for(var i =0; i < array_1.length;++i){ console.log("array_1["+i+"] ("+array_1[i]+"): " + parseBool(array_1[i]));}

for(var i =0; i < array_2.length;++i){ console.log("array_2["+i+"] ("+array_2[i]+"): " + parseBool(array_2[i]));}

for(var i =0; i < array_1.length;++i){ console.log(parseBool(array_1[i]));}
for(var i =0; i < array_2.length;++i){ console.log(parseBool(array_2[i]));}
```

Comment: if(str == null)  return false; will return random errors each time an input is wrongly initialized to null. Being tolerant is not a desirable feature most of the times:

Comment: @earizon: No, it will not "return random errors" - it will return false - BUT that behaviour may then cause random errors in your application. Feel free to instead throw an error if the value is null/undefined. Btw, now solved by overload strict = true. Pass strict = true, and you will now get an error on parse.

Comment: it depends on whether the invoked function is considered the "source of true" and invoking functions must adapt to its implementation, or whether the invoked function is an utility/service that must comply with what invoking functions are expecting according to "some contract". In general, coding conditional logic based on nulls force  knowledge by calling functions of internal implementation of called one. Throwing is safer and (much) simpler. 
https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=billion+dollar+mistake
(100% agree about using strict mode)

Answer (score 56):

I thought that @Steven 's answer was the best one, and took care of a lot more cases than if the incoming value was just a string. I wanted to extend it a bit and offer the following:

```
function isTrue(value){
    if (typeof(value) === 'string'){
        value = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
    switch(value){
        case true:
        case "true":
        case 1:
        case "1":
        case "on":
        case "yes":
            return true;
        default: 
            return false;
    }
}
```

It's not necessary to cover all the `false` cases if you already know all of the `true` cases you'd have to account for. You can pass anything into this method that could pass for a `true` value (or add others, it's pretty straightforward), and everything else would be considered `false`

Answer (score 47):

Universal solution with JSON parse:

```
function getBool(val) {
    return !!JSON.parse(String(val).toLowerCase());
}

getBool("1"); //true
getBool("0"); //false
getBool("true"); //true
getBool("false"); //false
getBool("TRUE"); //true
getBool("FALSE"); //false
```

UPDATE (without JSON):

```
function getBool(val){ 
    var num = +val;
    return !isNaN(num) ? !!num : !!String(val).toLowerCase().replace(!!0,'');
}
```

I also created fiddle to test it http://jsfiddle.net/remunda/2GRhG/

Comment: The 'without JSON' version has some flaw:

    val="0" ; console.log(!!(+val||String(val).toLowerCase().replace(!!0,'')) );

produces

   true

Comment: `getBool(undefined)` will crash When using the original JSON version and will return true for the 2nd version.  Here is a 3rd version which returns false:


function getBool(val) {
    var num;
    return val != null && (!isNaN(num = +val) ? !!num : !!String(val).toLowerCase().replace(!!0,''));
}

Answer (score 36):

Your solution is fine.

Using `===` would just be silly in this case, as the field's `value` will always be a `String`.

Comment: Why you think it would be silly to use `===`? In terms of performance it would be exactly the same if both types are Strings. Anyway, I rather use `===` since I always avoid the use of `==` and `!=`. Justifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use/359509#359509

Comment: Since `value` will always be a `string` neither `==` nor `===` are silly. Both are the right tool for this job. They only differ when the types are __not__ equal. In that case `===` simply returns `false` while `==` executes an intricate type coercion algorithm before comparison.

Comment: In most code styles, using `==` is bad practice. When you read the code and see `==`, it makes you stop and wonder is it a bug or some special trick. Therefore, it is better when your code is consistent. And `==` leaves room for a potential error in the future. Because types can change.

Comment: I'm not entierly sure I'd claim == makes you think there's a bug or trick... all of us C/++ coders are still wondering why there are 2 equality operators when u could just cast it (hooray weakly typed languages!  down w typescript!!).  =)

Answer (score 34):

The Boolean object doesn't have a 'parse' method. `Boolean('false')` returns true, so that won't work. `!!'false'` also returns `true`, so that won't work also.

If you want string `'true'` to return boolean `true` and string `'false'` to return boolean `false`, then the simplest solution is to use `eval()`. `eval('true')` returns true and `eval('false')` returns false.

**Keep in mind the performance and security implications when using `eval()` though**.

Comment: To understand what's "wrong" (or right) with eval - check out articles like http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/ or search on stackoverflow for 'Javascript eval malware'

Comment: I agree that `var isTrueSet = (myValue === 'true');` is the best answer.

Comment: I like that it's concise. But it fails spectacularly for the basic case of `eval('TRUE')`; proving once again, that `eval()` is evil.

Comment: @Area 51 Detective Fiction, in the same fashion, `JSON.parse('TRUE')` from the answer below also fails spectacularly. It's quite easy to force an error condition in JavaScript (or any language, for that matter). To account for this, you should normalize the string first, e.g., `var myValue = document.myForm.IS_TRUE.value.toLowerCase(); var isTrueSet = (myValue==='true' || myValue==='false') ? eval(myValue) : false;`

Comment: @10basetom: Quite correct. You should include `.toLowerCase()` in the answer is my point. I'm not trying to force anything. Uppercase `TRUE` is a common enough value to be returned by many UI widgets.

Comment: Quoting mozzila docs: 
`Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval().`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Answer (score 33):

```
var falsy = /^(?:f(?:alse)?|no?|0+)$/i;
Boolean.parse = function(val) { 
    return !falsy.test(val) && !!val;
};
```

This returns `false` for every falsy value and `true` for every truthy value except for `'false'`, `'f'`, `'no'`, `'n'`, and `'0'` (case-insensitive).

```
// False
Boolean.parse(false);
Boolean.parse('false');
Boolean.parse('False');
Boolean.parse('FALSE');
Boolean.parse('f');
Boolean.parse('F');
Boolean.parse('no');
Boolean.parse('No');
Boolean.parse('NO');
Boolean.parse('n');
Boolean.parse('N');
Boolean.parse('0');
Boolean.parse('');
Boolean.parse(0);
Boolean.parse(null);
Boolean.parse(undefined);
Boolean.parse(NaN);
Boolean.parse();

//True
Boolean.parse(true);
Boolean.parse('true');
Boolean.parse('True');
Boolean.parse('t');
Boolean.parse('yes');
Boolean.parse('YES');
Boolean.parse('y');
Boolean.parse('1');
Boolean.parse('foo');
Boolean.parse({});
Boolean.parse(1);
Boolean.parse(-1);
Boolean.parse(new Date());
```

Comment: I feel bad for those who don't scroll and just pick the top answer. This answer is robust, reusable, and succinct.

I shortened it into a one-liner:

`Boolean.parse ??= (val) => {return !/^(?:f(?:alse)?|no?|0+)$/i.test(val) && !!val};`

Answer (score 24):

There are a lot of answers and it's hard to pick one. In my case, I prioritise the performance when choosing, so I create [this jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/cast-booleans) that I hope can throw some light here.

Brief of results (the higher the better):

1. [**Conditional statement**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/2824333): 2,826,922
2. [**Switch case on Bool object**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2114091/2824333): 2,825,469
3. [**Casting to JSON**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833897/2824333): 1,867,774
4. [**!! conversions**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285901/2824333): 805,322
5. [**Prototype of String**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264180/2824333): 713,637

They are linked to the related answer where you can find more information (pros and cons) about each one; specially in the comments.

Comment: "something went wrong" when trying to view jsPerf test

Answer (score 21):

This has been taken from the accepted answer, but really it has a very weak point, and I am shocked how it got that count of upvotes, the problem with it that you have to consider the case of the string because this is case sensitive

```
var isTrueSet = (myValue.toLowerCase() === 'true');
```

Comment: not to mention that `.toLowerCase` might throw if `myValue` is equal to `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 19):

I use the following:

```
function parseBool(b) {
    return !(/^(false|0)$/i).test(b) && !!b;
}
```

This function performs the usual Boolean coercion with the exception of the strings "false" (case insensitive) and "0".

Answer (score 19):

## Simplest solution

### with ES6+

use the **logical NOT** twice **[ !! ]** to get the string converted

Just paste this expression...

```
const stringToBoolean = (string) => string === 'false' ? false : !!string
```

And pass your string to it!

```
stringToBoolean('')                 // false
stringToBoolean('false')            // false
stringToBoolean('true')             // true
stringToBoolean('hello my friend!') // true
```

Bonus!

```
const betterStringToBoolean = (string) => 
  string === 'false' || string === 'undefined' || string === 'null' || string === '0' ?
  false : !!string
```

You can include other strings at will to easily extend the usage of this expression...:

```
betterStringToBoolean('undefined')     // false
betterStringToBoolean('null')          // false
betterStringToBoolean('0')             // false
betterStringToBoolean('false')         // false
betterStringToBoolean('')              // false
betterStringToBoolean('true')          // true
betterStringToBoolean('anything else') // true
```

Comment: How about `'1'`? Should it be converted to `true` or `false`? I think it is should be `true`, no? But using your answer, it will returns `false`

Comment: Guess you are doing something wrong bro... I just tested the code and if you input ```' 1 '``` the return is always ```true```. Don't know how you got that ```false``` but I think you must be messing it up in some way

Comment: Ah sorry! My bad, I was testing the first function instead. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Your examples are all strings. For example `'null'` is not actual `null`, it's a string with characters `null` in it.

Answer (score 18):

The expression you're looking for simply is

```
/^true$/i.test(myValue)
```

as in

```
var isTrueSet = /^true$/i.test(myValue);
```

This tests `myValue` against a regular expression , case-insensitive, and doesn't modify the prototype.

Examples:

```
/^true$/i.test("true"); // true
/^true$/i.test("TRUE"); // true
/^true$/i.test("tRuE"); // true
/^true$/i.test(" tRuE"); // false (notice the space at the beginning)
/^true$/i.test("untrue"); // false (some other solutions here will incorrectly return true
/^true$/i.test("false");// returns false
/^true$/i.test("xyz");  // returns false
```

Comment: This is very neat.

Answer (score 17):

you can use `JSON.parse` as follows:

```js
   
var trueOrFalse='True';
result =JSON.parse(trueOrFalse.toLowerCase());
if(result==true)
  alert('this is true');
else 
  alert('this is false');
```

in this case `.toLowerCase` is important

Comment: Not guaranteed to return a boolean, though.

Answer (score 14):

```
Boolean.parse = function (str) {
  switch (str.toLowerCase ()) {
    case "true":
      return true;
    case "false":
      return false;
    default:
      throw new Error ("Boolean.parse: Cannot convert string to boolean.");
  }
};
```

Comment: You can use true.toString() instead of "true" to be even more clean :-)

Comment: Don't change globals, try to keep your changes isolated, maybe create a new `function parseBoolean` instead

Answer (score 14):

There are already so many answers available. But following can be useful in some scenarios.

```
// One can specify all values against which you consider truthy
var TRUTHY_VALUES = [true, 'true', 1];

function getBoolean(a) {
    return TRUTHY_VALUES.some(function(t) {
        return t === a;
    });
}
```

This can be useful where one examples with non-boolean values.

```
getBoolean('aa'); // false
getBoolean(false); //false
getBoolean('false'); //false

getBoolean('true'); // true
getBoolean(true); // true
getBoolean(1); // true
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm suprised that `includes` was not suggested

```js
let bool = "false"
bool = !["false", "0", 0].includes(bool)
```

You can modify the check for truely or include more conditions (e.g. `null`, `''`).

Comment: hmm, this is perfect

Comment: I'm using this approach for a framework that parses URL parameters and includes parameters without values as an empty string, something like: `example.com?useSpecialFeature` ends up as `{useSpecialFeature:''}`

Answer (score 13):

To convert both string("true", "false") and boolean to boolean

```
('' + flag) === "true"
```

Where `flag` can be

```
 var flag = true
 var flag = "true"
 var flag = false
 var flag = "false"
```

Answer (score 12):

This function can handle string as well as Boolean true/false.

```
function stringToBoolean(val){
    var a = {
        'true':true,
        'false':false
    };
    return a[val];
}
```

Demonstration below:

```js
function stringToBoolean(val) {
  var a = {
    'true': true,
    'false': false
  };
  return a[val];
}

console.log(stringToBoolean("true"));

console.log(typeof(stringToBoolean("true")));

console.log(stringToBoolean("false"));

console.log(typeof(stringToBoolean("false")));

console.log(stringToBoolean(true));

console.log(typeof(stringToBoolean(true)));

console.log(stringToBoolean(false));

console.log(typeof(stringToBoolean(false)));

console.log("=============================================");
// what if value was undefined? 
console.log("undefined result:  " + stringToBoolean(undefined));
console.log("type of undefined result:  " + typeof(stringToBoolean(undefined)));
console.log("=============================================");
// what if value was an unrelated string?
console.log("unrelated string result:  " + stringToBoolean("hello world"));
console.log("type of unrelated string result:  " + typeof(stringToBoolean(undefined)));
```

Answer (score 11):

## One Liner

We just need to account for the "false" string since any other string (including "true") is already `true`.

```
function b(v){ return v==="false" ? false : !!v; }
```

**Test**

```
b(true)    //true
b('true')  //true
b(false)   //false
b('false') //false
```

---

#### A more exaustive version

```
function bool(v){ return v==="false" || v==="null" || v==="NaN" || v==="undefined" || v==="0" ? false : !!v; }
```

**Test**

```
bool(true)        //true
bool("true")      //true
bool(1)           //true
bool("1")         //true
bool("hello")     //true

bool(false)       //false
bool("false")     //false
bool(0)           //false
bool("0")         //false
bool(null)        //false
bool("null")      //false
bool(NaN)         //false
bool("NaN")       //false
bool(undefined)   //false
bool("undefined") //false
bool("")          //false

bool([])          //true
bool({})          //true
bool(alert)       //true
bool(window)      //true
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `!!v` instead of using `true` directly?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using this one

```
String.prototype.maybeBool = function(){

    if ( ["yes", "true", "1", "on"].indexOf( this.toLowerCase() ) !== -1 ) return true;
    if ( ["no", "false", "0", "off"].indexOf( this.toLowerCase() ) !== -1 ) return false;

    return this;

}

"on".maybeBool(); //returns true;
"off".maybeBool(); //returns false;
"I like js".maybeBool(); //returns "I like js"
```

Comment: This is good, but works only with String type. Imagine that this need be used by a variable that is maybe `"true"` or `true`. If come the second one, this will not work. Is possible make a `document.prototype`to use this wherever we want it?

Comment: This looks elegant. Great job! However, I noticed that overloading basic prototypes in large JS apps (that also need unit testing) might result in some unexpected behaviour (namely, when you want to iterate with "for" through an array that has the prototype overloaded, you'll get some properties that you wouldn't normally expect). You have been warned. ;)

Comment: a variant of yours  that accepts boolean too

function StringOrElse2Bool(sob){
    if (typeof sob  === "string") {
        return ["no", "false", "0", "off"].indexOf( sob.toLowerCase() ) !== -1  ? false : true;
    } else {
        return !!sob
    }

Answer (score 10):

why don't you try something like this

```
Boolean(JSON.parse((yourString.toString()).toLowerCase()));
```

It will return an error when some other text is given rather than true or false regardless of the case and it will capture the numbers also as

```
// 0-> false
// any other number -> true
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to separate (in your thinking) the value of your selections and the representation of that value.

Pick a point in the JavaScript logic where they need to transition from string sentinels to native type and do a comparison there, preferably where it only gets done once for each value that needs to be converted. Remember to address what needs to happen if the string sentinel is not one the script knows (i.e. do you default to true or to false?)

In other words, yes, you need to depend on the string's value. :-)

Answer (score 9):

another solution.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5p7qobn/)

```
var toBoolean = function(value) {
    var strValue = String(value).toLowerCase();
    strValue = ((!isNaN(strValue) && strValue !== '0') &&
        strValue !== '' &&
        strValue !== 'null' &&
        strValue !== 'undefined') ? '1' : strValue;
    return strValue === 'true' || strValue === '1' ? true : false
};
```

test cases run in node

```
> toBoolean(true)
true
> toBoolean(false)
false
> toBoolean(undefined)
false
> toBoolean(null)
false
> toBoolean('true')
true
> toBoolean('True')
true
> toBoolean('False')
false
> toBoolean('false')
false
> toBoolean('0')
false
> toBoolean('1')
true
> toBoolean('100')
true
>
```

Answer (score 8):

Hands down the easiest way (assuming you string will be 'true' or 'false') is:

```
var z = 'true';
var y = 'false';
var b = (z === 'true'); // will evaluate to true
var c = (y === 'true'); // will evaluate to false
```

***Always*** use the === operator instead of the == operator for these types of conversions!

Comment: What conversion were you talking about? :-)

Comment: When comparing string in javascript there is no difference between using the == or === operators when not using conversions. Here you are comparing to strings, therefore no type conversions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 8):

Like @Shadow2531 said, you can't just convert it directly. I'd also suggest that you consider string inputs besides "true" and "false" that are 'truthy' and 'falsey' if your code is going to be reused/used by others. This is what I use:

```
function parseBoolean(string) {
  switch (String(string).toLowerCase()) {
    case "true":
    case "1":
    case "yes":
    case "y":
      return true;
    case "false":
    case "0":
    case "no":
    case "n":
      return false;
    default:
      //you could throw an error, but 'undefined' seems a more logical reply
      return undefined;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little late, but I have a little snippet to do this, it essentially maintains all of JScripts truthey/falsey/*filthy*-ness but includes `"false"` as an acceptible value for false.

I prefer this method to the ones mentioned because it doesn't rely on a 3rd party to parse the code (i.e: eval/JSON.parse), which is overkill in my mind, it's short enough to not require a utility function and maintains other truthey/falsey conventions.

```
var value = "false";
var result = (value == "false") != Boolean(value);

// value = "true"  => result = true
// value = "false" => result = false
// value = true    => result = true
// value = false   => result = false
// value = null    => result = false
// value = []      => result = true
// etc..
```

Answer (score 8):

Holy god some of these answers are just wild.  I love JS and its infinite number of ways to skin a bool.

My preference, which I was shocked not to see already, is:

```
testVar = testVar.toString().match(/^(true|[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]*[1-9]+|yes)$/i) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 7):

My take on this question is that it aims to satisfy three objectives:

- Return true/false for truthy and falsey values, but also return true/false for multiple string values that would be truthy or falsey if they were Booleans instead of strings.
- Second, provide a resilient interface so that values other than those specified will not fail, but rather return a default value
- Third, do all this with as little code as possible.

The problem with using JSON is that it fails by causing a Javascript error. This solution is not resilient (though it satisfies 1 and 3):

```
JSON.parse("FALSE") // fails
```

This solution is not concise enough:

```
if(value === "TRUE" || value === "yes" || ...) { return true; }
```

I am working on solving this exact problem for [Typecast.js](http://typecastjs.org). And the best solution to all three objectives is this one:

```
return /^true$/i.test(v);
```

It works for many cases, does not fail when values like {} are passed in, and is very concise. Also it returns false as the default value rather than undefined or throwing an Error, which is more useful in loosely-typed Javascript development. Bravo to the other answers that suggested it!

Comment: Just to go back to your objectives, the only problem with your third & best solution is that it does not meet Objective #1 - it will only return true for a value of `'true'`, but not for any truthy input.  In order to make it meet Objective #1, it is only *slightly* more concise than Solution #2, and far less readable.

Comment: `return /^(true|yes|1|t|y)$/i.test(str);`

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way which I always use:

```
let value = 'true';
let output = value === 'true';
```

Comment: Ternary operator is not necesary. Only with let output = value === 'true' works.

Comment: let value = 'true';
let output = value === 'true' ? true : false;
output = true;

let value = 'false';
let output = value === 'true' ? true : false;
output = false;

What is not working here?

Comment: Sorry, it has been a missunderstanding. That works perfectly, but it's redundant. value === 'true' already returns a boolean value and ternary operator is not necesary.

Comment: Yeah sure you are right, I edited my answered - my fault ;]

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a function to match PHP's filter_var which does this nicely. Available in a gist: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/7389368

```
/**
 * Parses mixed type values into booleans. This is the same function as filter_var in PHP using boolean validation
 * @param  {Mixed}        value 
 * @param  {Boolean}      nullOnFailure = false
 * @return {Boolean|Null}
 */
var parseBooleanStyle = function(value, nullOnFailure = false){
    switch(value){
        case true:
        case 'true':
        case 1:
        case '1':
        case 'on':
        case 'yes':
            value = true;
            break;
        case false:
        case 'false':
        case 0:
        case '0':
        case 'off':
        case 'no':
            value = false;
            break;
        default:
            if(nullOnFailure){
                value = null;
            }else{
                value = false;
            }
            break;
    }
    return value;
};
```

Comment: yours was almost what I was looking for. Here's my variation:
```
function parseBool( value, nullOnFailure = false )
{
 let value2 = parseFloat( value )
 if( !isNaN( value2 ))
  return !!value2
 if( typeof value !== 'string' )
  return !!value
 switch( value.trim().toLowerCase() )
 {
  case 't':
  case 'true':
  case 'on':
  case 'y':
  case 'yes':
   return true
  case 'f':
  case 'false':
  case 'off':
  case 'n':
  case 'no':
   return false
  default:
   return nullOnFailure ? null : false
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function isTrue(val) {
    try {
        return !!JSON.parse(val);
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the one I use.  Yes you could attempt to widen the net and support more values but how far do you go?  So "TRUE" should return true?  What about "tRuE".  Or "yes". Or "Y".  And why stick to just English - maybe the French "oui" should return true?? where does it end?  This answer lets javascript itself make the decision

Answer (score 6):

```js
const boolTrue = JSON.parse("true")
const boolFalse = JSON.parse("false")


console.log(boolTrue) // true
console.log(boolFalse) // false
```

To convert string boolean like "true" to actually boolean value is just wrapping to `JSON.parse()`
example: `JSON.parse("true")`

Answer (score 6):

## Dead-simple, best performing and strict

Best performance according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588344/7333766

Type safe and strict answer (great if you want to enforce stricter rules on your inputs) that I did not see in all other answers, also gives you a clear explanation in the console when it gets an incorrect input:

Typescript version:

```
function parseBool(value: any):boolean {
  if (value === 'true') return true
  if (value === 'false') return false
  console.error('parseBool got an unexpected value:', value, '(accepted values : "true", "false")')
  throw new Error('Error: parseBool got unexpected value')
}
```

Arrow function version:

```
const parseBool = (value: any):boolean => {
  if (value === 'true') return true
  if (value === 'false') return false
  console.error('parseBool got an unexpected value:', value, '(accepted values : "true", "false")')
  throw new Error('Error: parseBool got unexpected value')
}
```

Javascript version:

```
function parseBool(value){
  if (value === 'true') return true
  if (value === 'false') return false
  console.error('parseBool got an unexpected value:', value, '(accepted values : "true", "false")')
  throw new Error('Error: parseBool got unexpected value')
}
```

Comment: You should consider normal Boolean values also in the function in case they are passed to the function.

Comment: You may also want to consider using `.toLowerCase` to ensure you comparing the same cases, if it's case-insensitive.

Comment: you can add JSX use case <input checkbox={jsonResponse.value==="true"?true:false} /> which comes handy in mapping of retrieved json from API  in your JSX

Answer (score 5):

```
function parseBool(value) {
    if (typeof value === "boolean") return value;

    if (typeof value === "number") {
        return value === 1 ? true : value === 0 ? false : undefined;
    }

    if (typeof value != "string") return undefined;

    return value.toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: For a string, I personnally would have returned `true` for "true" like you did, but `false` for "false" only, and `undefined` otherwise. Sort of what you previously made with the integer case.

Answer (score 5):

I use an own method which includes a check if the object exists first and a more intuitive conversion to boolean:

```
function str2bool(strvalue){
  return (strvalue && typeof strvalue == 'string') ? (strvalue.toLowerCase() == 'true' || strvalue == '1') : (strvalue == true);
}
```

The results are:

```
var test; // false
var test2 = null; // false
var test3 = 'undefined'; // false
var test4 = 'true'; // true
var test5 = 'false'; // false
var test6 = true; // true
var test7 = false; // false
var test8 = 1; // true
var test9 = 0; // false
var test10 = '1'; // true
var test11 = '0'; // false
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/av5xcj6s/

Answer (score 5):

Lots of fancy answers here. Really surprised no one has posted this solution:

```
var booleanVal = toCast > '';
```

This resolves to true in most cases other than bool false, number zero and empty string (obviously). You can easily look for other falsey string values after the fact e.g.:

```
var booleanVal = toCast > '' && toCast != 'false' && toCast != '0';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String(true).toLowerCase() == 'true'; // true
String("true").toLowerCase() == 'true'; // true
String("True").toLowerCase() == 'true'; // true
String("TRUE").toLowerCase() == 'true'; // true

String(false).toLowerCase() == 'true'; // false
```

If you are not sure of the input, the above works for boolean and as well any string.

Comment: Or `true.toString()==='true'`. Also, why are you making `String(true)` and `String('true')` lowercase? lol

Answer (score 5):

If you are certain that the test subject is always a string, then explicitly checking that it equals `true` is your best bet.

You may want to consider including an extra bit of code just in case the subject could actually a boolean.

```
var isTrueSet =
    myValue === true ||
    myValue != null &&
    myValue.toString().toLowerCase() === 'true';
```

This could save you a bit of work in the future if the code gets improved/refactored to use actual boolean values instead of strings.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple way is

```
a = 'True';
a = !!a && ['1', 'true', 1, true].indexOf(a.toLowerCase()) > -1;
```

Comment: Here's mine
`function boolify(value = false) {
 return ["true", "1", "yes", "y", "on"].indexOf(String(value).toLowerCase()) != -1;
}`

Answer (score 4):

If there's some other code that's converting the boolean value to a string, you need to know exactly how that code stores true/false values. Either that or you need to have access to a function that reverses that conversion.

There are infinitely many ways to represent boolean values in strings ("true", "Y", "1", etc.). So you shouldn't rely on some general-purpose string-to-boolean converter, like Boolean(myValue). You need to use a routine that reverses the original boolean-to-string conversion, whatever that is.

If you know that it converts true booleans to "true" strings, then your sample code is fine. Except that you should use === instead of ==, so there's no automatic type conversion.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that using '1' and an empty value '' for boolean values works far more predictably than 'true' or 'false' string values... specifically with html forms since uninitialized/empty values in Dom elements will consistently evaluate to false whereas *any* value within them evaluates to true.

For instance:

```
<input type='button' onclick='this.value = tog(this.value);' />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function tog(off) {
        if(off) {
            alert('true, toggle to false');
            return '';
        } else {
            alert('false, toggle to true');
            return '1';
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Just seemed like an easier road, so far it's been very consistent/easy... perhaps someone can determine a way to break this?

Answer (score 4):

@guinaps> Any string which isn't the empty string will evaluate to true by using them.

How about using the String.match() method

```
var str="true";
var boolStr=Boolean(str.match(/^true$/i));
```

this alone won't get the 1/0 or the yes/no, but it will catch the TRUE/true, as well, it will return false for any string that happens to have  "true" as a substring.

**EDIT**

Below is a function to handle true/false, 1/0, yes/no (case-insensitive)

```
​function stringToBool(str) {
    var bool;
    if (str.match(/^(true|1|yes)$/i) !== null) {
        bool = true;
    } else if (str.match(/^(false|0|no)*$/i) !== null) {
        bool = false;
    } else {
        bool = null;
        if (console) console.log('"' + str + '" is not a boolean value');
    }
    return bool;
}

stringToBool('1'); // true
stringToBool('No'); // false
stringToBool('falsey'); // null ("falsey" is not a boolean value.)
stringToBool(''); // false
```

Comment: As written (on 2018 Dec 19 at 16:00 Z), `/^(false|0|no)*$/i` will match an empty string (which may be the intent) but also matches any number `false`, `0`, or `no`, for instance `"0falseno0nofalse0"` will also evaluate to `false` but should evaluate to `null` and output a console message that it is not a Boolean value.

Answer (score 4):

I do this, which will handle 1=TRUE=yes=YES=true, 0=FALSE=no=NO=false:

```
BOOL=false
if (STRING)
  BOOL=JSON.parse(STRING.toLowerCase().replace('no','false').replace('yes','true'));
```

Replace STRING with the name of your string variable.

If it's not null, a numerical value or one of these strings:
"true", "TRUE", "false", "FALSE", "yes", "YES", "no", "NO"
It will throw an error (intentionally.)

Comment: `JSON.parse` is able to handle parsing 'true' and 'false' to Boolean values, so you don't need to wrap it in `Boolean()`.

Answer (score 4):

In nodejs by using [node-boolify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-boolify) it is possible

**Boolean Conversion Results**

```
Boolify(true); //true
Boolify('true'); //true
Boolify('TRUE'); //null
Boolify(1); //true
Boolify(2); //null
Boolify(false); //false
Boolify('false'); //false
Boolify('FALSE'); //null
Boolify(0); //false
Boolify(null); //null
Boolify(undefined); //null
Boolify(); //null
Boolify(''); //null
```

Comment: I'd rather not introduce a new dependency to the project just for converting a string to a boolean.

Comment: It is very light weight and also u can validate whether string is boolean

Comment: For such a simple task, a library would not be desirable especially when the library controls how a boolean is defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
/// Convert something to boolean
function toBoolean( o ) {
    if ( null !== o ) {
        let t = typeof o;
        if ( "undefined" !== typeof o ) {
            if ( "string" !== t ) return !!o;
            o = o.toLowerCase().trim();
            return "true" === o || "1" === o;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

toBoolean(false) --> false
toBoolean(true) --> true
toBoolean("false") --> false
toBoolean("true") --> true
toBoolean("TRue") --> true
toBoolean("1") --> true
toBoolean("0") --> false
toBoolean(1) --> true
toBoolean(0) --> false
toBoolean(123.456) --> true
toBoolean(0.0) --> false
toBoolean("") --> false
toBoolean(null) --> false
toBoolean() --> false
```

Comment: this is so awesome and useful - thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

It would be great if there was a function on the String object that did this for us, but we can easily add our own prototypes to extend the String object.

Add this code somewhere in your project before you use it.

```
String.prototype.toBoolean = function() {
   return String(this.valueOf()).toLowerCase() === true.toString();
};
```

Try it out like this:

```
var myValue = "false"
console.log("Bool is " + myValue.toBoolean())
console.log("Bool is " + "False".toBoolean())
console.log("Bool is " + "FALSE".toBoolean())
console.log("Bool is " + "TRUE".toBoolean())
console.log("Bool is " + "true".toBoolean())
console.log("Bool is " + "True".toBoolean())
```

So the result of the original question would then be:

```
var myValue = document.myForm.IS_TRUE.value;
var isTrueSet = myValue.toBoolean();
```

Comment: Boolean.prototype is fully supported in all browsers

Answer (score 3):

```
if (String(a) == "true"){
  //true block
} else {
  //false block
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i wrote a helper function that handles your cases (and some more). Feel free to alter it to your specific needs

```
/**
 * @example
 * <code>
 * var pageRequestParams = {'enableFeatureX': 'true'};
 * toBool(pageRequestParams.enableFeatureX);  // returns true
 *
 * toBool(pageRequestParams.enableFeatureY, true, options.enableFeatureY)
 * </code>
 * @param {*}value
 * @param {Boolean}[mapEmptyStringToTrue=false]
 * @param {Boolean}[defaultVal=false] this is returned if value is undefined.
 *
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * @example
 * <code>
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': ''        }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': ''        }.enableFeatureX, true);    // true
 * toBool({                            }.enableFeatureX, true);    // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 0         }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': '0'       }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': '0 '      }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'false'   }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'falsE '  }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'no'      }.enableFeatureX);          // false
 *
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 1         }.enableFeatureX);          // true
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': '-2'      }.enableFeatureX);          // true
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'true'    }.enableFeatureX);          // true
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'false_'  }.enableFeatureX);          // true
 * toBool({'enableFeatureX': 'john doe'}.enableFeatureX);          // true
 * </code>
 *
 */
var toBool = function (value, mapEmptyStringToTrue, defaultVal) {
    if (value === undefined) {return Boolean(defaultVal); }
    mapEmptyStringToTrue = mapEmptyStringToTrue !== undefined ? mapEmptyStringToTrue : false; // default to false
    var strFalseValues = ['0', 'false', 'no'].concat(!mapEmptyStringToTrue ? [''] : []);
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return (strFalseValues.indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) === -1);
    }
    // value is likely null, boolean, or number
    return Boolean(value);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my 1 liner submission: I needed to evaluate a string and output, true if 'true', false if 'false' and a number if anything like '-12.35673'.

```
val = 'false';

val = /^false$/i.test(val) ? false : ( /^true$/i.test(val) ? true : val*1 ? val*1 : val );
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution i have been using it for a while

```
function asBoolean(value) {

    return (''+value) === 'true'; 

}


// asBoolean(true) ==> true
// asBoolean(false) ==> false
// asBoolean('true') ==> true
// asBoolean('false') ==> false
```

Answer (score 3):

## The fastest safe way to convert a string to a boolean in one line of code

One of features that help to fasten the code execution in Javascript is *Short-Circuit Evaluation*:

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.

So that if you want to test a string value for being `true` of `false` in `JSON.parse` way of test and keep the performance strong, you may use the `||` operator to exclude the slow code from execution in case the test value is of boolean type.

```
test === true || ['true','yes','1'].indexOf(test.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1
```

As the `Array.prototype.indexOf()` method is a part of *ECMA-262* standard in the 5th edition, you may need a **polyfill** for the old browsers support.

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {

    var k;

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing
    //    the this value as the argument.
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
    }

    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
    //    internal method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
    //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
    var n = +fromIndex || 0;

    if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
      n = 0;
    }

    // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }

    // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
    // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
    //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
    k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

    // 9. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {
      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
      //    HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
      //        internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
      //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
      //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
      //        searchElement and elementK.
      //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
      if (k in O && O[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
      k++;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this simple approach (using "myVarToTest"):

```
var trueValuesRange = ['1', 1, 'true', true];

myVarToTest = (trueValuesRange.indexOf(myVarToTest) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Take it easy using this lib.

https://github.com/rohmanhm/force-boolean

you just need to write a single line

```
const ForceBoolean = require('force-boolean')

const YOUR_VAR = 'false'
console.log(ForceBoolean(YOUR_VAR)) // it's return boolean false
```

It's also support for following

```
 return false if value is number 0
 return false if value is string '0'
 return false if value is string 'false'
 return false if value is boolean false
 return true if value is number 1
 return true if value is string '1'
 return true if value is string 'true'
 return true if value is boolean true
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple function that will do the trick,

```
   function convertStringToBool(str){
        return ((str === "True") || (str === "true")) ? true:false;
    }
```

This will give the following result

```
convertStringToBool("false") //returns false
convertStringToBool("true") // returns true
convertStringToBool("False") // returns false
convertStringToBool("True") // returns true
```

Comment: wouldn't `return str.toLowerCase() === 'true'` simpler?

Comment: Ah! you are 100% correct :) . Wrote that answer a few years ago. A better ES6 way of achieving the same result would be: `const strToBool = (str) => str.toLowerCase() === 'true'`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this one when I get value from URL/Form or other source.

It is pretty universal one line piece of code.

Maybe not the best for performance, if you need to run it millions times let me know, we can check how to optimize it, otherwise is pretty good and customizable.

```
boolResult = !(['false', '0', '', 'undefined'].indexOf(String(myVar).toLowerCase().trim()) + 1);
```

Result:

```
myVar = true;  // true
myVar = 'true';  // true
myVar = 'TRUE';  // true
myVar = '1';  // true
myVar = 'any other value not related to false';  // true

myVar = false; // false
myVar = 'false';  // false
myVar = 'FALSE';  // false
myVar = '0';  // false
```

Answer (score 3):

For TypeScript we can use the function:

```
export function stringToBoolean(s: string, valueDefault: boolean = false): boolean {
    switch(s.toLowerCase())
    {
        case "true":
        case "1":
        case "on":
        case "yes":
        case "y":
            return true;

        case "false":
        case "0":
        case "off":
        case "no":
        case "n":
            return false;
    }

    return valueDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution (it works like a charm!):

```
function convertStrToBool(str)
    {
        switch(String(str).toLowerCase())
            {
                case 'undefined': case 'null': case 'nan': case 'false': case 'no': case 'f': case 'n': case '0': case 'off': case '':
                    return false;
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            };
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Many of the existing answers use an approach that is semantically similar to this,
but I think there is value in mentioning that the following "one liner" is often sufficient. For example, in addition to the OP's case (strings in a form) one often wants to read environment variables from [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) in [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) (whose values, to the best of my knowledge, are always strings) in order to enable or disable certain behaviors, and it is common for these to have the form `SOME_ENV_VAR=1`.

```
const toBooleanSimple = (input) => 
  ['t', 'y', '1'].some(truePrefix => truePrefix === input[0].toLowerCase());
```

A slightly more robust and expressive implementation might look like this:

```
/**
 * Converts strings to booleans in a manner that is less surprising
 * to the non-JS world (e.g. returns true for "1", "yes", "True", etc.
 * and false for "0", "No", "false", etc.)
 * @param input
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function toBoolean(input) {
  if (typeof input !== 'string') {
    return Boolean(input);
  }
  const s = input.toLowerCase();
  return ['t', 'y', '1'].some(prefix => s.startsWith(prefix));
}
```

A (jest) unit test for this might look like this:

```
describe(`toBoolean`, function() {
  const groups = [{
    inputs: ['y', 'Yes', 'true', '1', true, 1],
    expectedOutput: true
  }, {
    inputs: ['n', 'No', 'false', '0', false, 0],
    expectedOutput: false
  }]
  for (let group of groups) {
    for (let input of group.inputs) {
      it(`should return ${group.expectedOutput} for ${JSON.stringify(input)}`, function() {
        expect(toBoolean(input)).toEqual(group.expectedOutput);
      });
    }      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In typescript, a small function to handle if the value was passed as a string, number or a boolean e.g. 'true', 'false', true, false, 1, or 0.

```
const getAsBoolean = (value: string | boolean | number) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value === 'true';
  } else if (typeof value === 'boolean' || typeof value === 'number') {
    return Boolean(value);
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this snippet to convert Numbers and Booleans:

```
var result = !isNaN(value) ? parseFloat(value) : /^\s*(true|false)\s*$/i.exec(value) ? RegExp.$1.toLowerCase() === "true" : value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on Steven's answer above, I wrote this function as a generic parser for string input:

```
parse:
  function (value) {
    switch (value && value.toLowerCase()) {
      case null: return null;
      case "true": return true;
      case "false": return false;
      default: try { return parseFloat(value); } catch (e) { return value; }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    MyLib.Convert.bool = function(param) {
         var res = String(param).toLowerCase();
         return !(!Boolean(res) || res === "false" || res === "0");
     };
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the existing answers are similar, but most ignore the fact that the given argument could also be an object.

Here is something I just whipped up:

```
Utils.parseBoolean = function(val){
    if (typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String){
        return /true/i.test(val);
    } else if (typeof val === 'boolean' || val instanceof Boolean){
        return new Boolean(val).valueOf();
    } else if (typeof val === 'number' || val instanceof Number){
        return new Number(val).valueOf() !== 0;
    }
    return false;
};
```

...and the unit test for it

```
Utils.Tests = function(){
    window.console.log('running unit tests');

    var booleanTests = [
        ['true', true],
        ['false', false],
        ['True', true],
        ['False', false],
        [, false],
        [true, true],
        [false, false],
        ['gibberish', false],
        [0, false],
        [1, true]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < booleanTests.length; i++){
        var lhs = Utils.parseBoolean(booleanTests[i][0]);
        var rhs = booleanTests[i][1];
        var result = lhs === rhs;

        if (result){
            console.log('Utils.parseBoolean('+booleanTests[i][0]+') === '+booleanTests[i][1]+'\t : \tpass');
        } else {
            console.log('Utils.parseBoolean('+booleanTests[i][0]+') === '+booleanTests[i][1]+'\t : \tfail');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter way to write this, could be `var isTrueSet = (myValue === "true") ? true : false;` Presuming only "true" is true and other values are false.

Comment: If you wanted it short why not writing just `var isTrueSet = myValue === "true";` ?

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate both boolean and boolean-like strings like boolean I used this easy formula:

```
var trueOrStringTrue = (trueOrStringTrue === true) || (trueOrStringTrue === 'true');
```

As is apparent, it will return true for both true and 'true'. Everything else returns false.

Answer (score 2):

Take care, maybe in the future the code change and return boolean instead of one string at the moment.

The solution would be:

```
//Currently
var isTrue = 'true';
//In the future (Other developer change the code)
var isTrue = true;
//The solution to both cases
(isTrue).toString() == 'true'
```

Answer (score 2):

**WARNING:** *Never* use this method for untrusted input, such as URL parameters.

You can use the `eval()` function.
Directly pass your string to `eval()` function.

```js
console.log(eval('true'), typeof eval('true'))
console.log(eval('false'), typeof eval('false'))
```

Comment: There are so many more performant and safer ways to do this.

Comment: This isn't a recommended solution. Read more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 2):

The strongest way is the following because it also handle undefined case:

```
    ({'true': true, 'false': false})[myValue];
```

```
    ({'true': true, 'false': false})[undefined] // => undefined
    ({'true': true, 'false': false})['true'] // => true
    ({'true': true, 'false': false})['false] // => false
```

Comment: What do we say this type of function ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function convertBoolean(value): boolean {
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
        value = value.toLowerCase();
    }
    switch (value) {
        case true:
        case "true":
        case "evet": // Locale
        case "t":
        case "e": // Locale
        case "1":
        case "on":
        case "yes":
        case 1:
            return true;
        case false:
        case "false":
        case "hayır": // Locale
        case "f":
        case "h": // Locale
        case "0":
        case "off":
        case "no":
        case 0:
            return false;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds too specific. Mind explaining it?

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand of Boolean(value) is !!value, this is because ! converts a value to the opposite of what it currently is, and then ! reverses it again back to original form.

Answer (score 1):

```
function returnBoolean(str){

    str=str.toString().toLowerCase();

    if(str=='true' || str=='1' || str=='yes' || str=='y' || str=='on' || str=='+'){
        return(true);
    }
    else if(str=='false' || str=='0' || str=='no' || str=='n' || str=='off' || str=='-'){
        return(false);
    }else{
        return(undefined);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean.parse()` does exist in some browser implementations.  It's definitely not universal, so if that's something that you need than you shouldn't use this method.  But in Chrome, for example (I'm using v21) it works just fine and as one would expect.

Comment: `Boolean("false")` => `true`

Answer (score 1):

You even do not need to convert the string to boolean. just use the following:
`var yourstring = yourstringValue  == 1 ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1):

To Get Boolean values from string or number Here is good solution:

```
var boolValue = Boolean(Number('0'));

var boolValue = Boolean(Number('1'));
```

First will return `false` and second will return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var trueVals = ["y", "t", "yes", "true", "gimme"];
var isTrueSet = (trueVals.indexOf(myValue) > -1) ? true : false;
```

or even just

```
var trueVals = ["y", "t", "yes", "true", "gimme"];
var isTrueSet = (trueVals.indexOf(myValue) > -1);
```

Similar to some of the switch statements but more compact. The value returned will only be true if the string is one of the trueVals strings. Everything else is false. Of course, you might want to normalise the input string to make it lower case and trim any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

**Convert String to Boolean**

```
var vIn = "true";
var vOut = vIn.toLowerCase()=="true"?1:0;
```

**Convert String to Number**

```
var vIn = 0;
var vOut = parseInt(vIn,10/*base*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is a most comprehensive use case

```
function parseBoolean(token) {
  if (typeof token === 'string') {
    switch (token.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'on':
      case 'yes':
      case 'ok':
      case 'ja':
      case 'да':
      // case '':
      // case '':
        token = true;
        break;
      default:
        token = false;
    }
  }
  let ret = false;
  try {
    ret = Boolean(JSON.parse(token));
  } catch (e) {
    // do nothing or make a notification
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML the values of attributes eventually become strings. To mitigate that in undesired situations you can have a function to conditionally parse them into values they represent in the JavaScript or any other programming langauge of interest.

Following is an explanation to do it for reviving boolean type from the string type, but it can be further expanded into other data types too, like numbers, arrays or objects.

In addition to that JSON.parse has a [revive parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Examples) which is a function. It also can be used to achieve the same.

Let's call a string looking like a *boolean*, "true", a *boolean string* likewise we can call a string like a number, "1", a *number string*. Then we can determine if a string is a *boolean string*:

```
const isBooleanString = (string) => ['true', 'false'].some(item => item === string);
```

After that we need to parse the *boolean string* as JSON by `JSON.parse` method:

```
JSON.parse(aBooleanString);
```

However, any string that is not a *boolean string*, *number string*, or any stringified object or array (any invalid JSON) will cause the `JSON.parse` method to throw a `SyntaxError`.

So, you will need to know with what to call it, i.e. if it is a *boolean string*. You can achieve this by writing a function that makes the above defiend *boolean string* check and call `JSON.parse`:

```
function parse(string){
  return isBooleanString(string) ? JSON.parse(string)
    : string;
}
```

One can further generalize the `isBooleanString` utility to have a more broader perspective on what qualifies as a *boolean string* by further parametrizing it to accept an optional array of accepted *boolean* strings:

```
const isBooleanString = (string, spec = ['true', 'false', 'True', 'False']) => spec.some(item => item === string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const result: Boolean = strValue === "true" ? true : false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use an `if` statment:

```js
function parseBool(str) {
  if (str.toLowerCase() == 'true') {
    var val = true;
  } else if (str.toLowerCase() == 'false') {
    var val = false;
  } else {
    //If it is not true of false it returns undefined.//
    var val = undefined;
  }
  return val;
}
console.log(parseBool(''), typeof parseBool(''));
console.log(parseBool('TrUe'), typeof parseBool('TrUe'));
console.log(parseBool('false'), typeof parseBool('false'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use a variable, if you know that 'true' will always be lowercase you can use this which will return true or false:

```
(eval(yourBooleanString == 'true'))
```

Comment: It should be noted that using `eval` for trivial cases like this is NOT RECOMMENDED. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done in 1 liner with a use arrow function

```
const convertStringToBoolean = (value) => value ? String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true' : false;
```

You guys can run and test various cases with following code snippet

```js
const convertStringToBoolean = (value) => value ? String(value).toLowerCase() === 'true' : false;

console.log(convertStringToBoolean("a"));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(null));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(undefined));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean("undefined"));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(true));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(false));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(0));
console.log(convertStringToBoolean(1)); // only case which will not work
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure the input is anything only within 'true' and 'false'
why not :

```js
let x = 'true' ;
//let x = 'false';
let y = x === 'true' ? true : false;
console.log(typeof(y), y);
```

Comment: same as   y= (x=='true');

Answer (score 1):

## ES6+

```js
const string = "false"
const string2 = "true"

const test = (val) => (val === "true" || val === "True")
console.log(test(string))
console.log(test(string2))
```

Comment: Pass "True" to this and it returns false

Comment: @opticyclic ok, i minded this and created a fix.

Comment: val.toLowerCase() === "true"

Answer (score 1):

```js
function parseBool(value: any, defaultsOnUndefined?: boolean) {
  if (['true', true, 1, '1', 'yes'].includes(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (['false', false, 0, '0', 'no', null].includes(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  return defaultsOnUndefined;
}
```

OR

```js
function parseBool(value: any) {
  if (['true', true, 1, '1', 'yes'].includes(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this, especially if you're getting the 'true' or 'false' from an input type of radio ie

```
     <input type='radio' name='IsAllowedToWork' value={true} onChange{handleChange} />

     <input type='radio' name='IsAllowedToWork' value={false} onChange{handleChange} />
```

is this

```
    const handleChange = (e) => {
      let { value ,type} = e.target;
      if (type==='radio') {
       value = JSON.parse(value);
      } else if (type === 'file') {
       value = e.target.files[0];
      }  
     setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: value });
    };
```

Comment: For radio buttons, you should use `.checked`

Answer (score 1):

If you have no shame:

```
String.prototype.toTruth = function () {
    const value = this.valueOf();
    return value === 'true' ? true : value === 'false' ? false : undefined;
};

'true'.toTruth()    // true
'false'.toTruth()   // false
'falsest'.toTruth() // undefined
''.toTruth()        // undefined
```

(Disclaimer: For the love of ECMA, don't do this.)

It's an interesting question, though, with more repercussions than one might expect.

I called it `toTruth` and not `toBoolean` because its return value can't always be a Boolean. One could argue that `''` should return `false`, but what about other strings? Is it `true` or `false`?

Unless you use strict typing everywhere, with a `'true' | 'false'` union, there's no guarantee that your string is going to contain either `true` or `false` (or nothing). So logically, you have to allow for a third value, `undefined`. (Or throw an error? No thanks.)

This means it actually becomes [ternary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic), where [`undefined`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_value) is similar to SQL's `NULL` (neither `true` nor `false`). That makes it much more complicated than a simple `true`/`false` predicate. Especially when you add JavaScript's [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) to the equation, where an `undefined` value might be evaluated as `false` ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).

If you have no shame and actually want to use this (dear god), you should explicitly check against the value you want with `===` and not use negation (unless you know what you're doing, keep in mind that it's ternary logic):

```
const input = 'foo'; // or anything else but 'true' or 'false'

input.toTruth()                // undefined

!input.toTruth()               // true (misleading, it's not false)
input.toTruth() !== true       // true (misleading, it's not false)

input.toTruth() === false      // false (correct)
input.toTruth() === true       // false (correct)
input.toTruth() === undefined  // true (correct)
```

I like JavaScript and I like ternary logic. But carelessly combining the two is a recipe for disaster.

A statically typed language like TypeScript does make it a lot easier. However, the same caveats apply when your code is exposed to code or input you don't control.

```
type BooleanString = 'true' | 'false'

function toBoolean(predicate: BooleanString): boolean {
    return predicate === 'true';
}

function toTruth(predicate: string): boolean | undefined {
    return predicate === 'true' ? true : predicate === 'false' ? false : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would be enough

```
String.prototype.boolean = function() {
    return "true" == this; 
};

"true".boolean() // returns true "false".boolean() // returns false
```

Comment: Modifying the prototype is very bad idea

Comment: @SzymonWygnański: i disagree. I do not see any other reason apart from for--in loop and native support for the same functionality by browsers.

Reg for-inloop: i cannot think of a case, where for-in loops are really needed in string.
Reg native support: we can definitely add a proto prop until native  browsers support, if we are not building a framework like - prototype or jquery, etc... More about this by @Kangax(Perfection kills) is here. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:whgHc3cedK0J:perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: Consider: we can go even farther: "true".checkbox() would convert to checkbox, or "true".application() would convert to app:D Not only for-in loops fail but the style is wrong here. Where would you look for the code of this "boolean/checkbox/application" definition in a big app? Imagine world where every library would do thinks like that. Isn't it much better to define a class or function: checkbox("true") - it's just cleaner and almost the same amount of letters. You never know IF browsers will support your custom function until it's defined as a standard (like Object.create etc...).

Answer (score 0):

The `toBoolean' function returns false for null, undefined, '', 'false'. It returns true for any other string:

```
const toBoolean = (bool) => {
  if (bool === 'false') bool = false
  return !!bool
}

toBoolean('false') // returns false
```

Comment: So it would return true for "False", would it not?

Comment: @OskarBerggren It wouldn't. Look at the code, `if (bool === 'false') bool = false` then, when it runs `return !!bool` it's returning `!!false` which is `false`.

Comment: @JustinLiu jsfiddle certainly evaluates `toBoolean('False')` to `true` which I think is probably not a good idea. With respect to the actual question, which was about a string representing a boolean value, I frankly think it's a bad idea to return `true` for `"any "other" "random" "string"` - it should raise an error instead of assuming that a caller that sent an erroneous string is happy with having that interpreted as `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Environment Variables, use the following.
Works on Heroku. Environment variables are string values that has to be converted to boolean values.

```
// Create the database connection
    this.connection = new Sequelize({
      username: process.env.PG_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
      host: process.env.PG_HOST,
      port: process.env.PG_PORT,
      dialect: process.env.PG_DIALECT,
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
          require: process.env.PG_DIALECT_OPTION_SSL_REQUIRED === 'true', // <<< convert from string to bool
          rejectUnauthorized:
            process.env.PG_DIALECT_OPTION_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED === 'true', // <<< convert from string to bool
        },
      },
      logging: true,
    });
```

env file

```
# PostgreSQL Config
PG_USERNAME=ttubkcug
PG_PASSWORD=ea59cee2883e73c602e6c05b674cf16950d6a9f05ab
PG_DATABASE=d67potesdliv25
PG_HOST=ec2-23-333-45-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com
PG_PORT=5432
PG_DIALECT=postgres
PG_DIALECT_OPTION_SSL_REQUIRED=true
PG_DIALECT_OPTION_SSL_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=false
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the original question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

const toBoolean = (val) => _.isEqual(_.toLower(val), 'true');

const values = [0, 1, '', undefined, null, [], {}, new Date(), true, false, 'true', 'false', 'True', 'False'];

_.forEach(values, (value) => {
    console.log(`${value} : ${toBoolean(value)}`);
});
```

https://replit.com/@tokra1/toBoolean-w-Lodash?v=1

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Function` to return a `Boolean` value from string `"true"` or `"false"`

```js
const TRUE_OR_FALSE = str => new Function(`return ${str}`)();

const [TRUE, FALSE] = ["true", "false"];

const [T, F] = [TRUE_OR_FALSE(TRUE), TRUE_OR_FALSE(FALSE)];

console.log(T, typeof T); // `true` `"boolean"`

console.log(F, typeof F); // `false` `"boolean"`
```

Comment: That has the same issues (with security and performance) as `eval`

Comment: There's no issues using eval(), it's part of the JavaScript programming language specified in ECMA-262.

Comment: That's just ignorant/naive. Bad performance and content security policy restrictions are definitely issues with this solution.

Comment: I am neither ignorant nor naive. I know what I'm doing when I use `Function()` and/or `eval()`. You are talking about imaginary issues that don't exist. I'm my own browser I can get around any and all CSP, COEP, COOP, CORP, CORS to achieve my aims.

Comment: @Bergi When you use Ecmascript `import` you are literally executing code that you have no idea what is contained therein unless you wrote the code. So if you are going to be talking about `Function()` and `eval()` understand you are talking about Ecmascript `import` in the same way - that further remains a two-way binding after initial execution.

Comment: Well great if you can achieve your own aims with your own code in your own browser. That doesn't make it a good answer for everyone to use. Especially when trying to convert arbitrary strings of unknown provenance to booleans.

Comment: Sure it's a good answer. It's a tool in the JavaScript programming language tool box. It's no different from using Ecmascript Modules `import` for code you didn't write.

Answer (score -1):

Simple one line operation if you need Boolean `false` and `true` from the string values:

```
storeBooleanHere = stringVariable=="true"?true:false;
```

- storeBooleanHere - This variable will hold the boolean value
- stringVariable - Variable that has boolean stored as string

Comment: simplified version: storeBooleanHere = stringVariable.toLowerCase() !== 'false' ;

Answer (score -1):

I needed a code that converts any variable type into Boolean.
Here's what I came up with:

```js
const toBoolean = (x) => {
    if (typeof x === 'object') {
      for (var i in x) return true
      return false
    }
    return (x !== null) && (x !== undefined) && !['false', '', '0', 'no', 'off'].includes(x.toString().toLowerCase())
  }
```

Let's test it!

```js
const toBoolean = (x) => {
    if (typeof x === 'object') {
      for (var i in x) return true
      return false
    }
    return (x !== null) && (x !== undefined) && !['false', '', '0', 'no', 'off'].includes(x.toString().toLowerCase())
  }
  

  // Let's test it!
  let falseValues = [false, 'False', 0, '', 'off', 'no', [], {}, null, undefined]
  let trueValues = [  true, 'true', 'True', 1, -1, 'Any thing', ['filled array'], {'object with any key': null}]
  
  falseValues.forEach((value, index) => console.log(`False value ${index} of type ${typeof value}: ${value} -> ${toBoolean(value)}`))
  trueValues.forEach((value, index) => console.log(`True value ${index} of type ${typeof value}: ${value} -> ${toBoolean(value)}`))
```

You can remove words like "off" and "no" from the array if they don't match your case.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way to convert a string to a boolean is the following:

```
Boolean(<stringVariable>)
```

Comment: Boolean("false") === true // output true

Answer (score -3):

var isTrueSet = eval(myValue);

Answer (score -5):

works perfectly and very simple:

```
var boolean = "false";
boolean = (boolean === "true");

//boolean = JSON.parse(boolean); //or this way..
```

to test it:

```js
var boolean = "false";
boolean = (boolean === "true");

//boolean = JSON.parse(boolean); //or this way.. 

if(boolean == true){
    alert("boolean = "+boolean);
}else{
    alert("boolean = "+boolean);
}
```

Comment: my bad i have fixed the above snippet - works now. not sure how those inverted commas "" got in there! ;/ @HugoZapata

Comment: But the question is, how to convert a string to boolean. new Boolean("false") doesn't work, so your answer is not correct.

Comment: @HugoZapata updated the answer, yes was incorrect (but strangely was working before) updated answer works correctly now.

Comment: What is the point of the if/else? You are alert'ing the same thing in both branches.

Comment: @foxdonut because if boolean == false, then you can do something different in the else statement - the alert is just an example. even though its the same it outputs something different if the boolean var = true/false.

Answer (score -6):

// Try this in two ways convert a string to boolean

```
    const checkBoolean = Boolean("false"); 
    const checkBoolean1 = !!"false";  
    
    console.log({checkBoolean, checkBoolean1});
```

Comment: Isn't `Boolean("false")`  returns `true`

Answer (score -7):

[image: Possible ways to convert String to Boolean]
I recommend you to create a function like the third option in the image and place it in a helper class as export, and reuse this function when you need.

Comment: Downvoted because you posted an image of the code rather than the code itself.

Comment: @Wyck you failed to mention that presentation is nice.

Answer (score -25):

Just do a:

```
var myBool = eval (yourString);
```

Examples:

```
alert (eval ("true") == true); // TRUE
alert (eval ("true") == false); // FALSE
alert (eval ("1") == true); // TRUE
alert (eval ("1") == false); // FALSE
alert (eval ("false") == true); // FALSE;
alert (eval ("false") == false); // TRUE
alert (eval ("0") == true); // FALSE
alert (eval ("0") == false); // TRUE
alert (eval ("") == undefined); // TRUE
alert (eval () == undefined); // TRUE
```

This method handles the empty string and undefined string naturally as if you declare a variable without assigning it a value.

Comment: -1: Please don't advocate the use of eval (except perhaps for clever hacks and necessity).

Comment: that's a really bad and insecure use of eval. and it's not even clever. -1