# Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?

Tags: javascript, operators, equality, equality-operator, identity-operator

I'm using [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) to go through JavaScript, and it's returning many suggestions to replace `==` (two equals signs) with `===` (three equals signs) when doing things like comparing `idSele_UNVEHtype.value.length == 0` inside of an `if` statement.

Is there a performance benefit to replacing `==` with `===`?

Any performance improvement would be welcomed as many comparison operators exist.

If no type conversion takes place, would there be a performance gain over `==`?

Answer (score 7176, accepted):

The strict equality operator (`===`) behaves identically to the abstract equality operator (`==`) except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

Reference: [JavaScript Tutorial: Comparison Operators](https://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/jsgrpComparison.htm)

The `==` operator will compare for equality *after doing any necessary type conversions*.  The `===` operator will **not** do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return `false`. Both are equally quick.

To quote Douglas Crockford's excellent [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742),

> JavaScript has two sets of equality operators: `===` and `!==`, and their evil twins `==` and `!=`.  The good ones work the way you would expect.  If the two operands are of the same type and have the same value, then `===` produces `true` and `!==` produces `false`.  The evil twins do the right thing when the operands are of the same type, but if they are of different types, they attempt to coerce the values.  The rules by which they do that are complicated and unmemorable.  These are some of the interesting cases:

> ```
> '' == '0'           // false
> 0 == ''             // true
> 0 == '0'            // true
> ```

> ```
> false == 'false'    // false
> false == '0'        // true
> ```

> ```
> false == undefined  // false
> false == null       // false
> null == undefined   // true
> ```

> ```
> ' \t\r\n ' == 0     // true
> ```

[image: Equality Comparison Table]

> The lack of transitivity is alarming.  My advice is to never use the evil twins.  Instead, always use `===` and `!==`.  All of the comparisons just shown produce `false` with the `===` operator.

---

#### Update

A good point was brought up by [@Casebash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165495/casebash) in the comments and in [@Phillipe Laybaert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113570/philippe-leybaert) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957602/1288) concerning objects.  For objects, `==` and `===` act consistently with one another (except in a special case).

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];

var c = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var d = { x: 1, y: 2 };

var e = "text";
var f = "te" + "xt";

a == b            // false
a === b           // false

c == d            // false
c === d           // false

e == f            // true
e === f           // true
```

The special case is when you compare a primitive with an object that evaluates to the same primitive, due to its `toString` or `valueOf` method. For example, consider the comparison of a string primitive with a string object created using the `String` constructor.

```
"abc" == new String("abc")    // true
"abc" === new String("abc")   // false
```

Here the `==` operator is checking the values of the two objects and returning `true`, but the `===` is seeing that they're not the same type and returning `false`.  Which one is correct?  That really depends on what you're trying to compare.  My advice is to bypass the question entirely and just don't use the `String` constructor to create string objects from string literals.

**Reference**
https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: I'd also point out that 0 === -0 and NaN !== NaN, which can be confusing sometimes. If you want to differentiate ±0 and consider NaNs equal, use Object.is (ES2015)

Comment: Soft typing is a *feature*. Obviously Crockford is pointing out some of the "artifacts" of the design decision, but soft typing is still a feature. If used correctly, it's ***absolutely fine*** to use. Don't throw the baby away with the bathwater.

Comment: Why would you ever need to use `-0`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's a quirk of IEEE-754 floating point. There's no practical use for it, but because an IEEE-754 "double" is a ["signed magnitude"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) format, negative zero "exists". However, to avoid surprises, it's defined to equal positive zero. JavaScript (well, ECMAScript) [defines `(-0).toString()` as `"0"`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring), but not every language does (eg. in C#, `Math.Round(-0.1).ToString()` is `"-0"`). That can lead to weird fixes like `x == 0 ? 0 : x`.

Comment: @Cole: In `(-0).toString()` are you sure that `(-0)` even creates a negative zero?  (Probably related to whether sign characters are part of the syntax grammar for Javascript literals or, as in many other languages, `-0` is unary negation applied to a literal formed only of digits)

Comment: Found that like most languages, `(-0)` is application of unary minus to a literal formed only of digits: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals   But despite this, it [does form negative zero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-minus-operator).

Answer (score 1253):

#### Using the `==` operator (*Equality*)

```
true == 1; //true, because 'true' is converted to 1 and then compared
"2" == 2;  //true, because "2" is converted to 2 and then compared
```

#### Using the `===` operator (*Identity*)

```
true === 1; //false
"2" === 2;  //false
```

This is because the **equality operator `==` does type coercion**, meaning that the interpreter implicitly tries to convert the values before comparing.

On the other hand, the **identity operator `===` does not do type coercion**, and thus does not convert the values when comparing.

Comment: I don't think that _identity_ is the correct term here/  `===` checks equality and type (called _strict_).  _Idendity_ usually refers to 'sameness', which is provisioned by the `Object.is` function (as per ES2015).

Answer (score 894):

Here's an interesting visualisation of the equality comparison between `==` and `===`.

**Source: https://github.com/dorey/JavaScript-Equality-Table** ([demo](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/), [unified demo](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/))

---

### `var1 === var2`

When using `===` for JavaScript equality testing, everything is as is.
Nothing gets converted before being evaluated.

[image: Equality evaluation of === in JS]

### `var1 == var2`

When using `==` for JavaScript equality testing, some ***funky conversions*** take place.

[image: Equality evaluation of == in JS]

#### Summary of equality in Javascript

[image: Equality in Javascript]

---

#### Conclusion:

**Always use `===`**, unless you fully understand the [funky conversions](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/#two-equals) that take place with `==`.

Comment: A better '==' table:  https://algassert.com/visualization/2014/03/27/Better-JS-Equality-Table.html

Comment: At least == comparisons are commutative (i.e. (a==b) === (b==a))    XD

Comment: @imkzh Relations are more commonly called _symmetric_ rather than _commutative_. But what I actually came here to say: `==` is not transitive! (even when ignoring `NaN`)

Comment: @Feuermurmel: Can you give an example of when `==` is non-transitive?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the late response. @SNag Definitely. Take `a = []`, `b = false` and `c = [0]`.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: Wow, you're right. That bottom right quadrant of the diagram exposes the non-transitivity of the `==`. `[] == false` and `false == [0]` are both `true`, yet `[] == [0]` is `false`. But that strangely makes sense when you understand how arrays and boolean are compared in JS, versus how two arrays are compared.

Comment: @SNag There's a clear (but IMHO not good) reason behind it: In JS, there are value types (e.g. numbers, strings; "changing it" usually means changing the value of a variable) and reference types (e.g. object, arrays; "changing it" usually means modifying the referenced instance). `==` compares values for value types and references (same-instance) for reference types. This is all well and useful (being able to compare references is often helpful). But it all goes to hell when `==` coerces reference types for comparison, implicitly treating them like value types.

Comment: IMHO, `==` should always only compare values and either use the "current value" for reference types or fail when used on them and `===` should do exactly what it does (compare values for value types and references for reference types). So few programmers and many language designers don't understand the fundamental difference between value and reference types, which leads to pain points like these. ☹️

Comment: @rocketsarefast I don't think it's better, it's just a different way of organizing.

Answer (score 659):

In the answers here, I didn't read anything about what **equal** means. Some will say that `===` means **equal and of the same type**, but that's not really true. It actually means that **both operands reference the same object**, or in case of **value types, have the same value**.

So, let's take the following code:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];
var c = a;

var ab_eq = (a === b); // false (even though a and b are the same type)
var ac_eq = (a === c); // true
```

The same here:

```
var a = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var b = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var c = a;

var ab_eq = (a === b); // false (even though a and b are the same type)
var ac_eq = (a === c); // true
```

Or even:

```
var a = { };
var b = { };
var c = a;

var ab_eq = (a === b); // false (even though a and b are the same type)
var ac_eq = (a === c); // true
```

This behavior is not always obvious. There's more to the story than being equal and being of the same type.

The rule is:

***For value types (numbers):***
`a === b` returns true if `a` and `b` have the same value and are of the same type

***For reference types:***
`a === b` returns true if `a` and `b` reference the exact same object

***For strings:***
`a === b` returns true if `a` and `b` are both strings and contain the exact same characters

---

### Strings: the special case...

Strings are not value types, but in Javascript they behave like value types, so they will be "equal" when the characters in the string are the same and when they are of the same length (as explained in the third rule)

Now it becomes interesting:

```
var a = "12" + "3";
var b = "123";

alert(a === b); // returns true, because strings behave like value types
```

But how about this?:

```
var a = new String("123");
var b = "123";

alert(a === b); // returns false !! (but they are equal and of the same type)
```

I thought strings behave like value types? Well, it depends who you ask... In this case a and b are not the same type. `a` is of type `Object`, while `b` is of type `string`. Just remember that creating a string object using the `String` constructor creates something of type `Object` that behaves as a string *most of the time*.

Answer (score 288):

Let me add this counsel:

***If in doubt, read the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)!***

ECMA-262 is the specification for a scripting language of which JavaScript is a dialect. Of course in practice it matters more how the most important browsers behave than an esoteric definition of how something is supposed to be handled. But it is helpful to understand why **new String("a") !== "a"**.

Please let me explain how to read the specification to clarify this question. I see that in this very old topic nobody had an answer for the very strange effect. So, if you can read a specification, this will help you in your profession tremendously. It is an acquired skill. So, let's continue.

Searching the PDF file for === brings me to page 56 of the specification: **11.9.4. The Strict Equals Operator ( === )**, and after wading through the specificationalese I find:

> **11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm**
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces **true** or **false**. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>   1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return **false**.
>   2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return **true**.
>   3. If Type(x) is Null, return **true**.
>   4. If Type(x) is not Number, go to step 11.
>   5. If x is **NaN**, return **false**.
>   6. If y is **NaN**, return **false**.
>   7. If x is the same number value as y, return **true**.
>   8. If x is +0 and y is −0, return **true**.
>   9. If x is −0 and y is +0, return **true**.
>   10. Return **false**.
>   11. If Type(x) is String, then return **true** if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions); otherwise, return **false**.
>   12. If Type(x) is Boolean, return **true** if x and y are both **true** or both **false**; otherwise, return **false**.
>   13. Return **true** if x and y refer to the same object or if they refer to objects joined to each other (see 13.1.2). Otherwise, return **false**.

Interesting is step 11. Yes, strings are treated as value types. But this does not explain why **new String("a") !== "a"**. Do we have a browser not conforming to ECMA-262?

Not so fast!

Let's check the types of the operands. Try it out for yourself by wrapping them in **typeof()**. I find that **new String("a")** is an object, and step 1 is used: return **false** if the types are different.

If you wonder why **new String("a")** does not return a string, how about some exercise reading a specification? Have fun!

---

Aidiakapi wrote this in a comment below:

> From the specification
>
> **11.2.2 The new Operator**:
>
> If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
>
> With other words, if String wouldn't be of type Object it couldn't be used with the new operator.

**new** always returns an Object, even for **String** constructors, too. And alas! The value semantics for strings (see step 11) is lost.

And this finally means: **new String("a") !== "a"**.

Answer (score 112):

I tested this in Firefox with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) using code like this:

```js
console.time("testEquality");
var n = 0;
while (true) {
  n++;
  if (n == 100000)
    break;
}
console.timeEnd("testEquality");
```

and

```js
console.time("testTypeEquality");
var n = 0;
while (true) {
  n++;
  if (n === 100000)
    break;
}
console.timeEnd("testTypeEquality");
```

My results (tested five times each and averaged):

```
==: 115.2
===: 114.4
```

So I'd say that the miniscule difference (this is over 100000 iterations, remember) is negligible. Performance ***isn't*** a reason to do `===`. Type safety (well, as safe as you're going to get in JavaScript), and code quality is.

Comment: Now, how do these compare when there is an actual type coersion for `==` operator? Remember, that's when there's a performance boost.

Comment: MAJOR difference when tested properly for the aforementioned reasons of quicker to only check type inequality. https://jsfiddle.net/4jhuxkb2/

Comment: I think the time dif we see is because n is a number and so is 100000, you should check it on a string "1", I assume some parsing will happen and the time dif will raise

Answer (score 109):

In PHP and JavaScript, it is a strict equality operator. Which means, it will compare both type and values.

Answer (score 102):

In JavaScript it means of the same value and type.

For example,

```
4 == "4" // will return true
```

but

```
4 === "4" // will return false
```

Answer (score 100):

**Why `==` is so unpredictable?**

What do you get when you compare an empty string `""` with the number zero `0`?

`true`

Yep, that's right according to `==` an empty string and the number zero are the same time.

And it doesn't end there, here's another one:

```
'0' == false // true
```

**Things get really weird with arrays.**

```
[1] == true // true
[] == false // true
[[]] == false // true
[0] == false // true
```

**Then weirder with strings**

```
[1,2,3] == '1,2,3' // true - REALLY?!
'\r\n\t' == 0 // true - Come on!
```

It get's worse:

**When is equal not equal?**

```
let A = ''  // empty string
let B = 0   // zero
let C = '0' // zero string

A == B // true - ok... 
B == C // true - so far so good...
A == C // **FALSE** - Plot twist!
```

Let me say that again:

```
(A == B) && (B == C) // true
(A == C) // **FALSE**
```

And this is just the crazy stuff you get with primitives.

It's a whole new level of crazy when you use `==` with objects.

At this point your probably wondering...

**Why does this happen?**

Well it's because unlike "triple equals" (`===`) which just checks if two values are the same.

`==` does a ***whole bunch of other stuff***.

It has special handling for functions, special handling for nulls, undefined, strings, you name it.

It get's pretty wacky.

In fact, if you tried to write a function that does what `==` does it would look something like this:

```
function isEqual(x, y) { // if `==` were a function
    if(typeof y === typeof x) return y === x;
    // treat null and undefined the same
    var xIsNothing = (y === undefined) || (y === null);
    var yIsNothing = (x === undefined) || (x === null);

    if(xIsNothing || yIsNothing) return (xIsNothing && yIsNothing);

    if(typeof y === "function" || typeof x === "function") {
        // if either value is a string 
        // convert the function into a string and compare
        if(typeof x === "string") {
            return x === y.toString();
        } else if(typeof y === "string") {
            return x.toString() === y;
        } 
        return false;
    }

    if(typeof x === "object") x = toPrimitive(x);
    if(typeof y === "object") y = toPrimitive(y);
    if(typeof y === typeof x) return y === x;

    // convert x and y into numbers if they are not already use the "+" trick
    if(typeof x !== "number") x = +x;
    if(typeof y !== "number") y = +y;
    // actually the real `==` is even more complicated than this, especially in ES6
    return x === y;
}

function toPrimitive(obj) {
    var value = obj.valueOf();
    if(obj !== value) return value;
    return obj.toString();
}
```

**So what does this mean?**

It means `==` is complicated.

Because it's complicated it's hard to know what's going to happen when you use it.

Which means you could end up with bugs.

**So the moral of the story is...**

Make your life less complicated.

Use `===` instead of `==`.

The End.

Answer (score 92):

The **===** operator is called a strict comparison operator, it **does** differ from the **==** operator.

Lets take 2 vars a and b.

For **"a == b"** to evaluate to true a and b need to be the **same value**.

In the case of **"a === b"** a and b must be the **same value** and also the **same type** for it to evaluate to true.

Take the following example

```
var a = 1;
var b = "1";

if (a == b) //evaluates to true as a and b are both 1
{
    alert("a == b");
}

if (a === b) //evaluates to false as a is not the same type as b
{
    alert("a === b");
}
```

**In summary**; using the **==** operator might evaluate to true in situations where you do not want it to so using the **===** operator would be safer.

In the 90% usage scenario it won't matter which one you use, but it is handy to know the difference when you get some unexpected behaviour one day.

Answer (score 89):

### `===` checks same sides are equal in *type* as well as *value*.

---

### Example:

```
'1' === 1 // will return "false" because `string` is not a `number`
```

### Common example:

```
0 == ''  // will be "true", but it's very common to want this check to be "false"
```

### Another common example:

```
null == undefined // returns "true", but in most cases a distinction is necessary
```

---

From my long-time experience an *untyped* check is preferable because you do not care if the value is either `undefined`, `null`, `0`  or `""`

Another comparison approach is using `Object.is` and [here's a great informative answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30543212/104380).

Answer (score 76):

Javascript execution flow diagram for strict equality / Comparison '==='

[image: Javascript strict equality]

Javascript execution flow diagram for non strict equality / comparison '=='

[image: Javascript non equality]

Answer (score 58):

JavaScript `===` **vs** `==` .

```
0==false   // true
0===false  // false, because they are of a different type
1=="1"     // true, auto type coercion
1==="1"    // false, because they are of a different type
```

Answer (score 56):

It means **equality without type coercion**
type coercion means JavaScript do not automatically convert any other data types to string data types

```
0==false   // true,although they are different types

0===false  // false,as they are different types

2=='2'    //true,different types,one is string and another is integer but 
            javaScript convert 2 to string by using == operator 

2==='2'  //false because by using === operator ,javaScript do not convert 
           integer to string 

2===2   //true because both have same value and same types
```

Answer (score 50):

In a typical script there will be no performance difference. More important may be the fact that thousand "===" is 1 KB heavier than thousand "==" :) [JavaScript profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+performance) can tell you if there is a performance difference in your case.

But personally I would do what JSLint suggests. This recommendation is there not because of performance issues, but because type coercion means `('\t\r\n' == 0)` is true.

Answer (score 48):

***The equal comparison operator == is confusing and should be avoided.***

If you **HAVE TO** live with it, then remember the following 3 things:

1. **It is not transitive: *(a == b)* and *(b == c)* does not lead to *(a == c)***
2. **It's mutually exclusive to its negation: *(a == b)* and *(a != b)* always hold opposite Boolean values, with all a and b.**
3. **In case of doubt, learn by heart the following truth table:**

EQUAL OPERATOR TRUTH TABLE IN JAVASCRIPT

- Each row in the table is a set of 3 mutually "equal" values, meaning that any 2 values among them are equal using the equal == sign*

** STRANGE: note that any two values on the first column are not equal in that sense.**

```
''       == 0 == false   // Any two values among these 3 ones are equal with the == operator
'0'      == 0 == false   // Also a set of 3 equal values, note that only 0 and false are repeated
'\t'     == 0 == false   // -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
'\r'     == 0 == false   // -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
'\n'     == 0 == false   // -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
'\t\r\n' == 0 == false   // -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

null == undefined  // These two "default" values are not-equal to any of the listed values above
NaN                // NaN is not equal to any thing, even to itself.
```

Answer (score 41):

There is unlikely to be any performance difference between the two operations in your usage. There is no type-conversion to be done because both parameters are already the same type. Both operations will have a type comparison followed by a value comparison.

Answer (score 41):

Simply

`==` means **comparison** between operands **with** type coercion

and

`===` means **comparison** between operands **without** type coercion.

Type coercion in JavaScript means automatically converting data types to other data types.

For example:

```js
123 == "123"  // Returns true, because JS coerces string "123" to number 123
              // and then goes on to compare `123 == 123`.

123 === "123" // Returns false, because JS does not coerce values of different types here.
```

Answer (score 40):

**Yes!** It does matter.

`===` operator in javascript **checks value as well as type** where as `==` operator just checks **the value (does type conversion if required)**.

[image]

You can easily test it. Paste following code in an HTML file and open it in browser

```
<script>

function onPageLoad()
{
    var x = "5";
    var y = 5;
    alert(x === 5);
};

</script>

</head>

<body onload='onPageLoad();'>
```

You will get '**false**' in alert. Now modify the `onPageLoad()` method to `alert(x == 5);` you will get **true**.

Answer (score 39):

As a rule of thumb, I would generally use `===` instead of `==` (and `!==` instead of `!=`).

Reasons are explained in in the answers above and also Douglas Crockford is pretty clear about it ([JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)).

However there is **one single exception**:
`== null` is an efficient way to check for 'is null or undefined':

```
if( value == null ){
    // value is either null or undefined
}
```

For example jQuery 1.9.1 uses this pattern 43 times, and  the [JSHint syntax checker](http://www.jshint.com/docs/#options) even provides the `eqnull` relaxing option for this reason.

From the [jQuery style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/):

> Strict equality checks (===) should be used in favor of ==. The only
> exception is when checking for undefined and null by way of null.

```
// Check for both undefined and null values, for some important reason. 
undefOrNull == null;
```

EDIT 2021-03:

Nowadays [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment)
support the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
and the [Logical nullish assignment `(??=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), which allows a more concise way to
assign a default value if a variable is null or undefined, for example:

```js
if (a.speed == null) {
  // Set default if null or undefined
  a.speed = 42;
}
```

can be written as any of these forms

```js
a.speed ??= 42;
a.speed ?? a.speed = 42;
a.speed = a.speed ?? 42;
```

Comment: _“`== null` is an efficient way to check for ‘is `null` or `undefined`’”_ … [or `document.all`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-IsHTMLDDA-internal-slot-aec).

Answer (score 34):

`===` operator  checks the values as well as the types of the variables for equality.

`==` operator just checks the value of the variables for equality.

Answer (score 34):

It's a strict check test.

It's a good thing especially if you're checking between 0 and false and null.

For example, if you have:

```
$a = 0;
```

Then:

```
$a==0; 
$a==NULL;
$a==false;
```

All returns true and you may not want this. Let's suppose you have a function that can return the 0th index of an array or false on failure. If you check with "==" false, you can get a confusing result.

So with the same thing as above, but a strict test:

```
$a = 0;

$a===0; // returns true
$a===NULL; // returns false
$a===false; // returns false
```

Comment: In JavaScript, this is completely wrong and wrongly incomplete. `0 != null`. -1

Answer (score 33):

JSLint sometimes gives you unrealistic reasons to modify stuff. `===` has exactly the same performance as `==` if the types are already the same.

It is faster only when the types are not the same, in which case it does not try to convert types but directly returns a false.

So, *IMHO,* JSLint maybe used to write new code, but useless over-optimizing should be avoided at all costs.

Meaning, there is no reason to change `==` to `===` in a check like `if (a == 'test')` when you know it for a fact that a can only be a String.

Modifying a lot of code that way wastes developers' and reviewers' time and achieves nothing.

Comment: Interestingly, `a.length===4` is actually *slower* in Firefox than `a.length==4`. It is, by all means, a micro-optimization anyway, but this is contrary to what people claim.

Answer (score 29):

A simple example is

```
2 == '2'  -> true, values are SAME because of type conversion.

2 === '2'  -> false, values are NOT SAME because of no type conversion.
```

Answer (score 26):

The top 2 answers both mentioned == means equality and === means identity. Unfortunately, this statement is incorrect.

If both operands of == are objects, then they are compared to see if they are the same object. If both operands point to the same object, then the equal operator returns true. Otherwise,
the two are not equal.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];  
var b = [1, 2, 3];  
console.log(a == b)  // false  
console.log(a === b) // false
```

In the code above, both == and === get false because a and b are not the same objects.

That's to say: if both operands of == are objects, == behaves same as ===, which also means identity. The essential difference of this two operators is about type conversion. == has conversion before it checks equality, but === does not.

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that you might easily get into trouble since JavaScript have a lot of implicit conversions meaning...

```
var x = 0;
var isTrue = x == null;
var isFalse = x === null;
```

Which pretty soon becomes a problem. The best sample of why implicit conversion is "evil" can be taken from this code in [MFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) / C++ which actually will compile due to an implicit conversion from CString to HANDLE which is a pointer typedef type...

```
CString x;
delete x;
```

Which obviously during runtime does *very* undefined things...

Google for implicit conversions in C++ and [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) to get some of the arguments against it...

Comment: `0 == null` is false.

Answer (score 23):

From the [core javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> `===` Returns `true` if the operands are strictly equal (see above)
>   with no type conversion.

Answer (score 22):

**Equality comparison:**

Operator `==`

Returns true, when both operands are equal. The operands are converted to the same type before being compared.

```
>>> 1 == 1
true
>>> 1 == 2
false
>>> 1 == '1'
true
```

**Equality and type comparison:**

Operator `===`

Returns true if both operands are equal and of the same type. It's generally 
better and safer if you compare this way, because there's no behind-the-scenes type conversions.

```
>>> 1 === '1'
false
>>> 1 === 1
true
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is a handy comparison table that shows the conversions that happen and the differences between `==` and `===`.

As the conclusion states:

> "Use three equals unless you fully understand the conversions that take
>   place for two-equals."

http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score 21):

null and undefined are nothingness, that is,

```
var a;
var b = null;
```

Here `a` and `b` do not have values. Whereas, 0, false and '' are all values. One thing common beween all these are that they are all falsy values, which means they all **satisfy** falsy conditions.

So, the 0, false and '' together form a sub-group. And on other hand, null & undefined form the second sub-group. Check the comparisons in the below image. null and undefined would equal. The other three would equal to each other. But, they all are treated as falsy conditions in JavaScript.

[image]

This is same as any object (like {}, arrays, etc.), non-empty string & Boolean true are all truthy conditions. But, they are all not equal.

Answer (score 18):

****Operators === vs == ****

```
1 == true    =>    true
true == true    =>    true
1 === true    =>    false
true === true    =>    true
```

Answer (score 18):

JavaScript has both strict and type–converting comparisons. A strict comparison (e.g., `===`) is only true if the operands are of the same type. The more commonly used abstract comparison (e.g. `==`) converts the operands to the same Type before making the comparison.

- The equality (`==`) operator converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the string operand is converted to a number if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.

  Syntax:

  `x == y`

  Examples:

  ```
  3 == 3     // true
  "3" == 3   // true
  3 == '3'   // true
  ```
- The identity/strict equality(`===`) operator returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) with no type conversion.

  Syntax:

  `x === y`

  Examples:

  `3 === 3   // true`

For reference: *[Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)* (Mozilla Developer Network)

Answer (score 17):

If you are making a web application or a secured page you should always use (only when possible)

```
===
```

because it will will check if it is the same content and if it is the same type!

so when someone enters:

```
var check = 1;
if(check == '1') {
    //someone continued with a string instead of number, most of the time useless for your webapp, most of the time entered by a user who does not now what he is doing (this will sometimes let your app crash), or even worse it is a hacker searching for weaknesses in your webapp!
}
```

but with

```
var check = 1;
if(check === 1) {
    //some continued with a number (no string) for your script
} else {
    alert('please enter a real number');
}
```

a hacker will never get deeper in the system to find bugs and hack your app or your users

my point it is that the

```
===
```

will add more security to your scripts

of course you can also check if the entered number is valid, is a string, etc.. with other if statements inside the first example, but this is for at least me more easier to understand and use

The reason I posted this is that the word 'more secure' or 'security' has never been said in this conversation (if you look at iCloud.com it uses 2019 times === and 1308 times ==, this also means that you sometimes have the use == instead of === because it will otherwise block your function, but as said in the begin you should use === as much as possible)

Answer (score 13):

My reasoning process using emacs org-mode and node.js to run a test.

```
| use ==     | '' | '0' | false | 'false' | undefined | null | ' \t\r\n ' |
| ''         | x  | f   | t     | f       | f         | f    | f          |
| '0'        |    | x   | t     | f       | f         | f    | f          |
| false      |    |     | x     | f       | f         | f    | t          |
| 'false'    |    |     |       | x       | f         | f    | f          |
| undefined  |    |     |       |         | x         | t    | f          |
| null       |    |     |       |         |           | x    | f          |
| ' \t\r\n ' |    |     |       |         |           |      | x          | 



| use ===    | '' | '0' | false | 'false' | undefined | null | ' \t\r\n ' |
| ''         | x  | f   | f     | f       | f         | f    | f          |
| '0'        |    | x   | f     | f       | f         | f    | f          |
| false      |    |     | x     | f       | f         | f    | f          |
| 'false'    |    |     |       | x       | f         | f    | f          |
| undefined  |    |     |       |         | x         | f    | f          |
| null       |    |     |       |         |           | x    | f          |
| ' \t\r\n ' |    |     |       |         |           |      | x          |
```

My test script below: run > node xxx.js

```
var rowItems = ['', '0', false, 'false', undefined, null, ' \t\r\n ']
var colItems = rowItems

for(var i = 0; i < rowItems.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < colItems.length; j++) {
        var r = (rowItems[i] === colItems[j]) ? true : false;
        console.log(rowItems[i] + " = " + colItems[j] + " " + r + " [" + i + "] ==> [" + j + "]")
    };
}
```

Answer (score 12):

`===` cares if the objects are the same. Therefore, `new String("Hello world") === "Hello world"` returns false. However, `==` does not care about if the objects are the same; it just simply converts one argument into the other's type: if conversion is not possible, return false. Then `new String("Hello world") == "Hello world"` returns true instead of false.

Comment: This answer is a bit misguided, or, at least, not very precise… “objects”? Do you mean “types”? `==` _does_ care if the types are the same; it delegates to strict equality comparison if they are. Two objects are compared by reference, but that’s the case for both operators. _“if conversion is not possible”_ — I guess… but coercion is usually possible, and that’s not sufficient to cause one or the other result of the comparison, e.g. `"undefined" != undefined`, even though coercion would be possible.

Answer (score 11):

The javascript is a **weakly typed language** i.e. without any data-types as there in C,c++ eg. int, boolean, float etc. thus a variable can hold any type of value, that why these special comparison operators are there

Eg

```
var i = 20;var j = "20";
```

if we apply comparison operators these variables result will be

```
i==j //result is true
```

or

```
j != i//result is false
```

for that we need a special comparison operators which checks for the **value as well as for the data type** of the variable

if we do

```
i===j //result is false
```

Answer (score 11):

`==` operator just compares the values not datatype.

`===` operator compare the values with comparison of its datatype.

eg :

```
1 == "1" //true

1 === "1" //false
```

This operator (`"==="`) used in languages which performs automatic type cast eg. PHP, Javascript.
`"==="` operator helps to prevent unexpected comparison caused by automatic typecast.

Comment: for '==' dataType  is not important

Comment: @mrmr68 The type of the operands of the [Abstract Equality Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) is _very_ important — it’s used to coerce the operands to other types so they can be compared.

Answer (score 8):

> Different's Between `=` , `= =` , `= = =`

- `=` operator Used to just assign the `value`.
- `= =` operator Used to just compares the `values` not `datatype`
- `= = =` operator Used to Compare the `values` as well as `datatype`.

Answer (score 7):

**always** use '**===**' and you will avoid thousand of mistakes. nowadays using **triple** equality is more preferable by different style guides, because it compares taking into account type of operands.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a big difference between equality `==` and identity `===` operators.
Usually the identity operator performs faster, because no types conversion is done. But if the values are of the same type, you'll see no difference.
Check my post [The legend of JavaScript equality operator](http://rainsoft.io/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/), which explains the details, including the types conversion & comparison algorithms, with a lot of examples.

Answer (score 5):

*One* unmentioned reason to use `===` - is in the case that you are co-existing with / cross-compiling to/from `coffee-script`. From The [Little Book on CoffeeScript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html)...

> The weak equality comparison in JavaScript has some confusing behavior and is often the source of confusing bugs.
>
> The solution is to instead use the strict equality operator, which consists of three equal signs: ===. It works exactly like the normal equality operator, but without any type coercion. It's recommended to always use the strict equality operator, and explicitly convert types if needs be.

If you are regularly converting to and from `coffee-script`, you should just use `===`.  In fact, the `coffee-script` compiler will **force you to**...

> CoffeeScript solves this by simply replacing all weak comparisons with strict ones, in other words converting all == comparators into ===. You can't do a a weak equality comparison in CoffeeScript, and you should explicitly convert types before comparing them if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First, some terminology about Javascript string equals: Double equals is officially known as the abstract equality comparison operator while triple equals is termed the strict equality comparison operator. The difference between them can be summed up as follows: Abstract equality will attempt to resolve the data types via type coercion before making a comparison. Strict equality will return false if the types are different. Consider the following example:

```
console.log(3 == "3"); // true
console.log(3 === "3"); // false.
console.log(3 == "3"); // true
console.log(3 === "3"); // false.
```

Using two equal signs returns true because the string “3” is converted to the number 3 before the comparison is made. Three equal signs sees that the types are different and returns false. Here’s another:

```
console.log(true == '1'); // true
console.log(true === '1'); // false
console.log(true == '1'); // true
console.log(true === '1'); // false
```

Again, the abstract equality comparison performs a type conversion. In this case both the boolean true and the string ‘1’ are converted to the number 1 and the result is true. Strict equality returns false.

If you understand that you are well on your way to distinguishing between == and ===. However, there’s some scenarios where the behavior of these operators is non intuitive. Let’s take a look at some more examples:

```
console.log(undefined == null); // true
console.log(undefined === null); // false. Undefined and null are distinct types and are not interchangeable.
console.log(undefined == null); // true     
console.log(undefined === null); // false. Undefined and null are distinct types and are not interchangeable.

console.log(true == 'true'); // false. A string will not be converted to a boolean and vice versa.
console.log(true === 'true'); // false
console.log(true == 'true'); // false. A string will not be converted to a boolean and vice versa.
console.log(true === 'true'); // false
```

The example below is interesting because it illustrates that string literals are different from string objects.

```
console.log("This is a string." == new String("This is a string.")); // true
console.log("This is a string." === new String("This is a string.")); // false
console.log("This is a string." == new String("This is a string.")); // true
console.log("This is a string." === new String("This is a string.")); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

## Strict equality is for the most part better

The fact that Javascript is a loosely typed language needs to be in the front of your mind constantly as you work with it. As long as the data structure is the same there really is no reason as to not use strict equality, with regular equality you often have an implicit conversion of values that happens automatically, this can have far-reaching effects on your code. It is very easy to have problems with this conversion seeing as they happen automatically.

With strict equality there is no automatic implicit conversion as the values must already be of the correct data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is loosely typed just like php is,

```
var x = "20";
var y =20;

if (x===y) // false
```

This will always give you a false because even though the values of the variables are the same, the data types are not

One is string the the other is int

```
If(x==y)//true
```

This however just checks if the content is the same, regardless of the data types...

I dont want to say the values are equal because a string value cannot be equal to an int value logically

Answer (score 1):

Use `===` if you want to compare couple of things in JavaScript, it's called **strict equality**, it means this will return true if **only both type and value are the same**, so there wouldn't be any unwanted type correction for you, if you using `==`, you basically don't care about the type and in many cases you could face issues with loose equality comparison.

**Strict equality using ===**

> Strict equality compares two values for equality. Neither value is
>   implicitly converted to some other value before being compared. If the
>   values have different types, the values are considered unequal.
>   Otherwise, if the values have the same type and are not numbers,
>   they're considered equal if they have the same value. Finally, if both
>   values are numbers, they're considered equal if they're both not NaN
>   and are the same value, or if one is +0 and one is -0.

```
var num = 0;
var obj = new String('0');
var str = '0';

console.log(num === num); // true
console.log(obj === obj); // true
console.log(str === str); // true

console.log(num === obj); // false
console.log(num === str); // false
console.log(obj === str); // false
console.log(null === undefined); // false
console.log(obj === null); // false
console.log(obj === undefined); // false
```

**Loose equality using ==**

> Loose equality compares two values for equality, after converting both
>   values to a common type.  After conversions (one or both sides may
>   undergo conversions), the final equality comparison is performed
>   exactly as === performs it.  Loose equality is symmetric: A == B
>   always has identical semantics to B == A for any values of A and B
>   (except for the order of applied conversions).

```
var num = 0;
var obj = new String('0');
var str = '0';

console.log(num == num); // true
console.log(obj == obj); // true
console.log(str == str); // true

console.log(num == obj); // true
console.log(num == str); // true
console.log(obj == str); // true
console.log(null == undefined); // true

// both false, except in rare cases
console.log(obj == null);
console.log(obj == undefined);
```

Comment: I do believe it's subjective in regards to what you should/should not do, and misleading to tell someone to always use a particular action. While I agree than in most cases we care to use '===' vs. '==', there may be a particular case where you want the type conversion done. - Cannot think of an exact use case off the top of my head, but perhaps the design is to have a loose check. Regardless, if something is included in the language, it's there for a reason. We should try to avoid blanketing statements of 'always do x' in my opinion.

Comment: I knid of agree with you, if you read my whole answer, you see I explain in more details later on,  to be honest there are not many cases we use and need loose comparation in Javascript... I can say less than 5 percent, even much less, but I use ´always´ for those people with no js background, which think == check strict comparation in JavaScript, they learn to be catious and not using it at first place, but as they get more expert, they know in which rare cases they might use it. That's why I write my answer like that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it suggest to replace `==` with `===` is that the `===` operator is more reliable than `==`. In our context reliable means `===` also goes for type checking. Considering the best programming practices we should always choose more reliable feature over less reliable one. Again whenever we think about exactly equal to operator most of the time, we are by default consider the type should be same. As `===` provides the same, we should go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The dilemma of "Should I use `==` or `===` in JavaScript comparison" is equal or analogous to a question of: "Should I use a 'spoon' or a 'fork' for eating.

The only reasonable answer to this question is that

1. You should use **Dynamic Type** comparison e.g.:`==` for ***loose Type*** comparisons.
2. You should use **Static Type** comparison e.g.:`===` for ***strong Type*** comparisons.

That's because they are not the same. They don't have the same purpose and are not meant to be used for the same purpose.

Of course both 'forks' and 'spoons' are meant for 'eating', but you will chose to use them accordingly to what you've been served to eat.

Meaning: you'll resolve to using a 'spoon' i.e.: `==` for having a 'soup', and / or the 'fork' i.e.: `===` for picking.

Asking if it is better to use a "fork" or a "spoon" for "eating" - is equall to asking if it is better to use a static [===] versus dynamic [==] eq., op. in JS. Both questions are equally wrong and reflect a very narrow or shallow understanding of the subject in question.

Comment: p.s.: JSLint (or Crockford ) is wrong for insisting, or asking you to use strict type comparison when dealing with values of the same type. The JavaScript `length` property is always of type: number. And therefore no room or a possibility for fake positives. Furthermore, there is no need for `dSele_UNVEHtype.value.length === 0` when you can use a direct shorthand of `!dSele_UNVEHtype.value.length` instead.

Comment: Why would you answer a 9 year old question, which already has 49 answers, which also has an accepted answer with over 5k upvotes, with an answer that contains a weird analogy and doesn't explain anything what has not been said already?

Comment: Because there are to many professional misuses of JavaScript no matter how old they are. And you for instance was unable to understand what's it all about and capture the essence of the difference Live Script makes in contrast to static type languages. And why do we need its intelligent dynamics. JavaScript  was made for creative intelligent people not for dorks.

Comment: Yes I agree there are many misuses of JavaScript. However I still think your analogy is weird as in it can be easily misunderstood, and it does not cover the core basics in a meaningful way.

Comment: The analogy given is the best ever illustration of their difference and the quality of use case. This is the best short essay to learn the absolute essence even if you are a complete newcomer to JS. And is equally good, probably better than my late answer on how to empty a JS array [for real].

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new String("123");
var b = "123";

alert(a === b); // returns false !! (but they are equal and of the same type)
```

Saw this in one of the answers.
`a` and `b` are not really the same type in this case, if you will check `typeof(a)`
 you will get *'object'* and `typeof(b)` is *'string'*.