# Converting a string into a boolean

Tags: javascript, string, asp-classic, boolean, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

I have a hidden field that contains a boolean value, I am checking if it's true or false in a JavaScript function, like this:

```
if (Trim(document.forms['mainform'].hiddenfield.value) == 'true')
{
}
```

which I think is a lame way to do this. How to convert that string value into a boolean?

Comment: The answer you selected does not work!

Comment: This is a dupe anyways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit silly, but you could add a method to String.

```
String.prototype.isTrue = function() {
   return this.toLowercase() == "true"
}
```

gives you

```
>>> "true".isTrue()
true
>>> var x = "false"
>>> x.isTrue()
false
```

just use .isTrue() on any string literal or variable.