# Does Adobe Flex SDK contain a helper function for converting strings to Booleans?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sdk, adobe, flex4

Yes, it is a trivial question.  I was just wondering.  Does the framework have a helper function that does something like this:

```
switch (value)
{
    case "true":
        return true;
    case "false":
        return false;
    default:
        return Boolean(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  See [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437902/parse-boolean-values-in-strings-for-use-with-function-apply).