# Converting string "true" / "false" to boolean value

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have a JavaScript string containing `"true"` or `"false"`.

How may I convert it to boolean without using the `eval` function?

Comment: JSON.parse('true') will return boolean true and JSON.parse('false') will return boolean false

Comment: this stuff solved everything like number and string format http://stackoverflow.com/a/42136805/5531595

Comment: @HariDas Worked perfectly! I'm surprised the Boolean object wrapper doesn't properly convert "true" and "false" strings. I think it should be allowed an optional second parameter that tells it to attempt converting the string value to a boolean

Answer (score 407, accepted):

```
var val = (string === "true");
```

Case insensitive:

```
const val = (string.toLowerCase() === "true");
```

Comment: This works.  It's probably better to add `var` before the declaration of `val`.

Comment: Even better with a triple equals ===

Comment: If you do somehting like: var string = new String('true'); var val = (string === 'true'); Then val will be false. you need to call .toString() on the string reference. This is especially applicable if you are doing this on a prototype / this reference to the string.

Comment: Another improvement is to change "string" to "string.toLowerCase()". This allows for "string" to have other encodings of true like "True" and "TRUE".

Comment: var val = string.match(/true/i); // case insensitive match

Comment: var val = string.match(/^(true|yes|t|y|1)$/i); /* case insensitive + many + whole word */

Comment: Instead of playing with regex, how about: `var val = (string.toLowerCase() === 'true');`

Comment: @MaxStrater that's an excellent idea. In my case, VB Razor is creating my string, which (because of VB's silliness) enters it as "True" or "False" (aka sentence case)

Comment: One can also use JSON.parse(var), if value is fetched from database and is of string type.

Comment: myValue === 'true'; is precisely equivalent to myValue == 'true';. There is no benefit in using === over == here

Comment: Very good @ Boushley!  
Happens exactly the same if you use TypeScript instead of JS. Many, many THANKs!  You just can't state `val = (objProp === "true")` if "by accident" `objProp ` is a (fake!) boolean.

Answer (score 27):

You could simply have: `var result = (str == "true")`.

Comment: `result = result === "true";`

Here the parentheses are unnecessary, but should check the type and value.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using the variable result:

```
result = result == "true";
```

Comment: If you're using the variable result:

`result = result === "true";` 
Here the parentheses are unnecessary, but should check the type and value.