# Pass boolean to Directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a ElementReady directive:

```
<div elem-ready="{function:'setHeightColleagueColumn()',attribute:'{{true}}'}">
```

Directive:

```
link: (scope, elem, attrs) => {
    const attributes = scope.$eval(attrs.elemReady);
    const x = attributes.attribute === 'true';
    const z = attributes.attribute;
}
```

In this case `x` is a boolean value because it compares 2 string values which returns a boolean value. But `z` is a string value.

This question > [AngularJS: passing boolean value to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985381/angularjs-passing-boolean-value-to-directive) shows you can use `{{ booleanvalue }}` to pass a boolean value to a directive. But that's not working in my case because I'm sending a object.

I have to use this directive in multiple components and I can't use scope because it will give `Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope` error on certain components, so I followed this suggestion:

[How do I pass multiple attributes into an Angular.js attribute directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546771/how-do-i-pass-multiple-attributes-into-an-angular-js-attribute-directive/38458515#38458515) — [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38458515/848706)

Any suggestions how I can pass a boolean value instead of a string value?

Answer (score 0):

Of course after rubber ducking this with Stackoverflow I see the issue:

```
,attribute:'{{true}}'}">
```

The `'` enclosing the `{{true}}` value will make this a boolean value. Removing the single quotes fixes the issue.

Don't even need the curly bracers around the boolean value :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass a Boolean in an AngularJS expression, simply use `true` or `false`, no quotes, no curly brackets:

```
<div elem-ready="{fn:'setHeightColleagueColumn()', bool: true }"></div>
```

### THE DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("elemReady", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        const obj = scope.$eval(attrs.elemReady);
        console.log(typeof obj.bool, obj.bool);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div elem-ready="{fn:'setHeightColleagueColumn()', bool: true }"></div>
</body>
```