# if statement in jquery Isn't working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

alert(x) is false. But for some reason it is not going into the if statement? Any ideas?

Html

```
 @{bool x = false;
            foreach (var c in Model.Cleaner.TimeConfirmations.Where(l => l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() || l.date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()))
            {
                     x = true;
            }
            <span class="ifAvailable" data-confirmationchecker="@x" value="15">@x</span>
           }
```

Jquery

```
var x = $(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationchecker')
alert(x);
if ( x == false) {
    alert("hi")
}
```

Comment: x values is something which is not false so that's why if is not being executed...

Comment: if you want to compare with false ..consider changing it to "false",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data attributes [can only contain strings](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp):

> The data-* attributes consist of two parts:
>
> 1. The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
> 2. **The attribute value can be any string**

So you're comparing the string "false" to the [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) false, which are not the same.

Instead of

```
if (x == false)
```

use

```
if (x == "false")
```

Or, you could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976714/converting-string-true-false-to-boolean-value):

```
var x = ($(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationchecker') == "true");
alert(x);
if ( x == false) {
    alert("hi")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It actually did not work with "false" only as "False"

Answer (score 1):

Your x is a string, convert the value into a boolean and then do the check

```
var x = $(".ifAvailable").data('confirmationchecker')
alert(x);
if (JSON.parse(x) == false) {
    alert("hi")
}
```

[How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the value of x is "false" string type, please  try :

```
if ( x == "false") {
    alert("hi")
}
```

or cast your variable x to a bool type.