# Can't convert string to boolean

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, variables, boolean

I'm trying to parse an *ini* file using [`ini`](https://github.com/npm/ini). However, I can't manage to convert my `string` value to a `boolean` and I think I'm going crazy!

I have tried the obvious `variable = (value == 'true');` approach listed below:

- [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)
- [Converting string "true" / "false" to boolean value [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976714/converting-string-true-false-to-boolean-value)

```js
    let myBool;
    for (const [key, value] of iniObject) {
        console.log(`pair: ${key} - ${value}`);
        if(key == 'testBool') {
            myBool = (value == 'true');
            console.log(`myBool set to ${myBool} (${typeof myBool}) - value: ${value}`);
        }
    }
```

Instead of setting `myBool` to true, it is set to false! The `console.log()` output is the following, showing that the input `value` is indeed "true":

```
    [1] pair: testBool - true
    [1] myBool set to false (boolean) - value: true
```

I have also tried the following without success:

```js
    myBool = (JSON.parse(value) == 'true');
or
    myBool = (value == 'true') ? true : false;
```

The corresponding line in the `ini` is `testBool=true`, so nothing special.
What am I missing? I feel like an idiot for having spent the last 3 hours on this, so I would **really** appreciate some help on this.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you try `console.log(typeof value, btoa(value))` and tell what it logs?

Comment: How are you splitting `testBool=true` ?

Comment: What is `typeof value` when key == 'testBool' ?

Comment: @Ivar: The output is: `[1] boolean dHJ1ZQ==`

Comment: So `value` is not a string value at all, it's already a boolean.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I was an idiot! So when I logged the object, I got quotations around everything, but somewhere along the line the values must have been parsed! D'oh! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the `ini` works, but did you check what is the type of `value`?

Maybe it has already parsed it as a boolean and that is why you get false when comparing?

```js
"true" == true // false
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. It was a `boolean` all along. :)