# String to Boolean using ternary operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a result coming from PHP side and `json_encode` send all the values as string (not as it's original type). The string coming at `quote_tax` is a `1|0` and of course this is `true|false` for example:

```
{
  "country_id": "3",
  "country_name": "Italy",
  "contract_tax": "1",
  "quote_tax": "0",
  "contract_inflation": "0",
  "quote_inflation": "0"
}
```

When I want to perform some operation based on such values and because they are coming as string I need to do something like this:

```
 data.quote_tax == '1' 
                ? $('#contract_tax').val(1).attr('checked', 'checked') 
                : $('#contract_tax').val(0).removeAttr('checked');
```

I did know about `.parseInt()` to convert them into a integer but I believe then I would need to have the same comparison but this case comparing with `INT`:

```
 data.quote_tax == 1 
                ? $('#contract_tax').val(1).attr('checked', 'checked') 
                : $('#contract_tax').val(0).removeAttr('checked');
```

I have tried this way:

```
 Boolean(data.quote_tax) == true 
                ? $('#contract_tax').val(1).attr('checked', 'checked') 
                : $('#contract_tax').val(0).removeAttr('checked');
```

And it doesn't work since `Boolean(data.quote_tax)` always evaluate as `true` even if `data.quote_tax = '0'`.

I have check this posts already but I couldn't found a proper solution:

- [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)
- [Convert string to Boolean in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344542/convert-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Any ideas what's wrong here or how to do this?

Comment: `"0"` is truthy as it’s a non-empty string. `""` and `0` are falsey. Try `Boolean(Number(data.quote_tax)) == true` or simply `+data.quote_tax` as the condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values in Javascript are either "truthy" or "falsy", meaning they'll be interpreted as `true` or `false` in a boolean context. In the case of numbers, `0` is `false` and all others are `true`. If you convert your value to a number, you don't have to perform any other conversion to treat it as a boolean.

```js
var x = parseInt('1');
x ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);

x = parseInt('0');
x ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
```

[See here for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: All answers are good but this one is so far the best one, thanks it works

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the operators - parse the string to a number, and then convert to Boolean:

```js
console.log(Boolean(parseInt('0', 10)));

console.log(!!parseInt('0', 10));

console.log(!!+'0');
```

Comment: Or just use `!!parseInt('0', 10);`

Answer (score 2):

Your last approach fails because any non-empty string evaluates to `true` if converted to a boolean, including `"0"`.

---

The integer `0` evaluates to false, while non-zero integers evaluate to `true`. For this reason, `parseInt(data.quote_tax) == 1` would be equivalent to `parseInt(data.quote_tax)` in your case.

---

However, I would stick with the first approach in this situation:

```
data.quote_tax == '1'
```

This requires no type conversions, the intent is immediately obvious and is also doesn't require the developer to know the things I listed above to be understood. **Don't make your code more complicated than it has to be.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
!!parseInt('1'); //true
!!parseInt('0'); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always try and stay away from [coercing types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript). The problem is that if you do as others have suggested, `if (x)` this works great for `0` & `1`. What if for some reason you get a `"false"`, `2`, `null` or `undefined`. What would you want your code to do here?

```js
undefined ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
null ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
NaN ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
2 ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
"false" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
"true" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
```

If you use `===` (as opposed to `==`) it [prevents Javascript coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). You can then test for the string value `"1"`

```js
"1" === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
1 === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
undefined === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
null === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
NaN === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
2 === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
"false" === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
"true" === "1" ? console.log(true) : console.log(false);
```

It now works a lot more consistently. May or may not be an issue in your case but I prefer this method for the just in case factor.