# JavaScript !!"false"

Tags: javascript

I expected !!"false" to return false i.e. !"false" would return true, so !!"false" would return "false", but when I tested it in the console, !!"false" returned true.

Why didn`t things happen as expected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/263965/125382). Voted to close.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"false"` is a non-empty string, which evaluates to `true`. Hence `!"false"` is `false` and `!!"false"` is `true`. You were probably thinking of `!!false`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is occurring because anything other than an empty string will return true.