# javascript : checking boolean values

Tags: javascript

I have a boolean value set as a hidden variable in the form and I have the below javascript .

```
         $().ready(function() {

             var flag =  $('#popUpFlag').val();

             alert("flag = "+flag);

             if(flag){
                alert("flag is true");
             }else{
                alert("flag is false");
             }
        })
```

These are the outputs for the alert .

```
         flag =
         flag is false


         flag = false
         flag is false


         flag = true
         flag is false
```

My concern is obviously the third output . When the flag is true , why is it printing "flag is false" , instead of "flag is true" . I tested it in IE8 and FF 4

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is this your only code? It should definitely not print `flag is false`. Are you doing anything else in between?

Comment: What this contain, string boolean??    $('#popUpFlag').val();

Comment: As @alex and @Shadow pointed out, `$('#popUpFlag').val()` will return a string, and not a boolean value. Now, every *non-empty* string evaluates to `true`, also `"false"`, but this does not explain your second case then. So you must be doing something else...

Comment: @Felix You are right. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you don't have a boolean value in the hidden field. The value in the field is always a string.

When you use the string value as if it was a boolean value, you get unexpected results. A condition is false if the value is `false`, `0`, `""` or `null`, but the string `"false"` is neither, so it's evaluated as `true`.

If you want a boolean value, you have to parse the string. An easy way is to simply check if the string has a specific value:

```
var flag =  $('#popUpFlag').val() === 'true';
```

Answer (score 6):

`flag` is a string, so have this instead:

```
if (flag === "true") {
  //true
}
else if (flag === "false") {
  //false
}
```

Comment: Even if `flag` is the string `"true"`, it should alert `flag is true`. But it is worth pointing out that it is a string and not a boolean.

Comment: And also `"false"` should be *truthy*.

Comment: @alex: Good point. So the second case is correct either. The OP os probably doing *something* but vice versa or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I suspect that the value you are using is a string, so you're seeing the value correctly in the alert, but not when it tries to look at it like a boolean.

[How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Just try ocnverting to boolean and see if it still gives you the same issue