# How do I evaulate a string value as a boolean in javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an asp.net webform with a textbox. The value of the textbox is "False" and has been verified by viewing the page source in the browser.

Despite being set to false the following code results in `beginDateReqd` being set to false and consequently, `DateParms` being displayed when it shouldn't be.

```
var beginDateReqd = Boolean($('.HiddenBeginDateTimeRequired').val());
if (beginDateReqd) {
    $('.DateParms').show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please check this existing question for more details.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safer would be first to convert value "toLowerCase" and then compare with "true" value:

```
var beginDateReqd = ($('.HiddenBeginDateTimeRequired').val().toLowerCase() == "true");
if (beginDateReqd) {
    $('.DateParms').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a comparison operator?

```
var beginDateReqd = ($('.HiddenBeginDateTimeRequired').val() == "True");
if (beginDateReqd) {
    $('.DateParms').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var beginDateReqd = parseBoolean ($('.HiddenBeginDateTimeRequired').val());
    if ( beginDateReqd  ) {
        $('.DateParms').show();
    }



function parseBoolean(str) {
  return /^true$/i.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Pardon my nitpick, but I'd either rename that function `isTrue()` or throw an error if the value is not either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Using regex for this is like going after a fly with a tactical nuclear strike... what's wrong with just `foo == "True"`?

Comment: @Polynomial - Do regular expressions perform worse than string comparison?  Can you point me to an article on the subject?  Personally, I like them - they are so much more precise and meaningful than doing eg `mystring.toLowerCase() == somestring`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Boolean` object does not parse string values for truthiness. You should be using a comparison operator or a regex test. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_boolean.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use comparison after making sure of the case

```
var beginDateReqd = ($('.HiddenBeginDateTimeRequired').val().toLowerCase() == "true");
```