# how we can covert a string to boolean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

I have a select list with 2 options in it, `yes` or `no`, something like:

```
   <select size="1">
     <option value="true">yes</option>
     <option value="false">no</option>
   </select>
```

Now i want to use the selected value in the jquery-UI button disabled property , means :

```
  $("button").button({ disabled : $("select").val() });
```

Now my problem is that the value which we will get by `$("select").val()` is `string` and for

`disabled` property we need boolean. So i want to know that is there any method just like

`pareInt` or `parseFloat` by which we can convert a string to boolean ?

Comment: because of the ambiguity, you should specify what you consider true or false... By nature, all non-empty strings are true, even the string `"false"`. Do you want this to happen? be more specific please

Comment: Probably you want to use <input type="checkbox",Also your question is more related to HTML DOM and not JavaScript itself. In HTML DOM for representing "false" what i often do is not assigning the attribute at all - then if the attribute has any value, even "false" consider it "true". Rememeber than in HTML attributes are always strings. Is up to you to decide which is the value of an empty string, I already give you my opinion : if the attribute is not declared, then is false. A technology that solves this pretty nicely is JSX and particularly TSX (typeScript JSX syntax)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var value = ('true' === $("select").val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the third one:

```
var num = +something; //toNumber
var str = something + ""; //toString
var bol = !!something; //toBoolean
```

That will turn `0, "", false, null, undefined, NaN` to `false`, and everything else to `true`

But using my deduction powers, you want something like `"false" -> false`, for this you can use one of these:

```
var bol = something === "true"; //false for anything different than true
var bol = something !== "false"; //true for anything different than false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
var myBool = myString == "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about writing your own?

I'm not exactly firm in JavaScript Syntax but try this:

```
function a(inputString)
    if(inputString == "true")
        return true;
    if(inputString == "false")
        return false;
```

I'm sure there are better solutions. This one is just from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myBoolean = (myString === 'true') ? true : false;
```

Comment: ternary operator not necessary, you can use the equality result directly: `var myBoolean = myString === 'true';`

Comment: someone really -1 because my comment?, it was just a minor improvement, not really a reason to dv :/

Comment: @ajax333221 true, that yours and accepted answer are more elegant. Plus, don't I just hate anonymous downvoters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

> $("select").val() == 'true'

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how many times you want to do it. If its going to be littered throughout your code I would add in a function like:

```
Boolean.parse = function (str) {
  switch (str.toLowerCase ()) {
    case "true":
      return true;
    case "false":
      return false;
    default:
      throw new Error ("Boolean.parse: Cannot convert string to boolean.");
  }
};
```