# JavaScript: Parsing a bool

Tags: javascript, parsing, boolean

Is there a single function (or language construct) I can use to evaluate only the following values to `true` (and any other values to `false`)?

```
var trueValues = [
    true,               // boolean literal
    "true",             // string literal
    "\t tRUe ",         // case-insensitive string literal with leading/trailing whitespace
    1,                  // number literal
    1.00,               // number literal
    "1",                // string literal of number literal
    "1.0",              // string literal of number literal
    "1.00000000"        // string literal of number literal
];
```

Comment: `!!~trueValues.indexOf(something)`. (You *did* specify "only the following values".)

Comment: Potential Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: all of the values you gave would evaluate to `true` when cast to a boolean anyways. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sounds a bit icky. You want `\t tRUe` to be `true`, but `\t tRe` to be `false`. Perhaps you should rethink your needs.

Comment: Anybody knows , how to distinguish `1.00` from `1`?

Comment: @Engineer ECMAScript doesn't provide a mechanism for telling the difference between exact value floats and integers.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean those as examples and you really mean:

1. Interpreted as a string, contains only the case-insensitive word "true" with optional surrounding whitespace.
2. Interpreted as a number, evaluates to exactly 1.

The following two conditions will filter out all exceptional values.

```
/^\s*true\s*$/i.test(value) || Number(value) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will trim any whitespace, change it to lowercase, and compare it to the string literal `true`. The other case that will return a `true` value is a number that returns `1` when passed to `parseInt()`

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  bool = (val.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '').toLowerCase() === "true" || Number(val) === 1)
} else {
  bool = (val.trim().toLowerCase() === "true" || Number(val) === 1)
}
```

Comment: Good point, updated to look more like your solution except with a fallback to `.trim()`... debatable which is better but I'm liking yours for its simplicity and readability.