# Acting on a boolean value in an Ajax jQuery call in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

i have the following jQuery function in my project

```
$.ajax({
            url: "WebServices/BrowserType.asmx/IsIE",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            success: function (msg) {
                If(msg.d== 'false')
                {
                    $("#Test2").html(msg);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error" + err.toString());
            }
        });
```

What i intend to do is to get a boolean value from my webservice and then act on the result on my jquery success option.

I had tried the following:

- I set the dataType to boolean (of course, i changed my method return type to bool) and in the success function of the jquery, i had

  ```
  success:function(){if (msg.d){$("#Test2").html(msg);}}
  ```

but an error was thrown. (Object. That's the error.)

- I tried setting the dataType to **text** (this time i changed my method return type to string) and in the success function of the jquery, i did it as in the above main code. This time there was no error but the success function seems not to work. However, when i removed the **If** statement from the above code, the success code worked.

Please how do i go about this. I had tried what i know. I intend to act on a boolean value. My web service returns either true or false and i want to act on the boolean value returned. The issue is how can i determine if the value returned is true or false in the success function of my ajax?

Your contribution is highly appreciated. I have edited this post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using

if (returnData.d==true){//Do something}else{//Don't do it}

Answer (score 0):

If your result is text, try converting it to boolean.
Check this out:

[How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)