# JavaScript parsing boolean

Tags: javascript

in the response from my server I get a JSON object. It has a boolean flag.

```
if(file.showInTable == 'true') {

}
```

But, even if `showInTable` is set to `false`, I get inside that code block. How to cope with that ?

I tried:

```
if(file.showInTable == 'true')
if(file.showInTable)
if(Boolean(file.showInTable))
```

### Edit

as Ghommey has mentioned, I've used the 2nd option to check that value. Even if the comparions statement returns `false`, it also gets inside the code. See the pic below

[image]

Comment: Please post the JSON response you get.

Comment: What is `typeof file.showInTable` ?

Comment: Is it set to the boolean value `false` or the string `'false'`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: Anthony Grist: it is set to false or true (as bool)

Comment: xdazz: in my class, it is typeof bool

Comment: @Tony We're going to need to see a lot more code to be able to definitively answer this. Let's see how you're making the call to get the JSON, the JSON response and the code that processes it.

Answer (score 2):

> it is set to false or true (as bool) - Tony

Why do you compare a boolean as a string?

Just compare it as a boolean:

```
if(file.showInTable === true) {

}
```

or

```
if(file.showInTable !== false) {

}
```

Comment: `file.showInTable === true` and `file.showInTable !== false` aren't the same comparison. `'true' === true` is false, whereas `'true' !== false` is true.

Comment: but Anthony, the thing here is, he receives a boolean object, so file.showInTable will be either `true` or `false` not `'true'` or `'false'`, OP was attempting to equal the boolean he was receiving to a string.

Comment: Was it not the complete opposite?

Comment: a strange thing. I've used the 2nd option to check it's value. When it's `true`, it gets inside, but if that comparsion statement returns `false`, it also gets inside

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but why not?

```
if (file.showInTable === "false") file.showInTable = false;
```