# Using the (!!!) operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

!! operator is obviously useful as it forces to check something that's not a boolean as a Boolean - that's for "True" conditions.

But what about false? Do you need to use !!!?

Comment: ! converts a value to the inverse boolean (if it was truthy it becomes false,falsy it becomes true)

Comment: `!val === !!!val` for any value of val

Comment: @Simon: I have never seen `====`. Assuming you mean strict comparison, how is a Boolean operation the opposite of comparison?

Comment: Is this question not not not a joke?

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn You should clarify that !value would suffice for a boolean conversion.

Comment: @Emissary People do come by !!! in other people's code and they need reassurance for their sanity. For example, Node.js (downloaded 5 days ago) uses !!!value in their assert.js. [Github shows that they've changed it in July 2013 though.](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/dc9acd4faeba1aade414bdd8da28f30b16773575) Why does my version of Node not reflect this?

Comment: There is no `(!!!)` operator in JavaScript. `(!!!) true` → `Exception: expected expression, got ')'`

Answer (score 4):

One `!` would be enough :)

```
!1 // false
!0 // true
```

Comment: No, not if something comes back as undefined. !! forces undefined to be converted to true.

Comment: @antonpug: You sure about that?  http://jsfiddle.net/kkf7Y/  A single `!` seems to work just fine, at least in my browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686583/can-someone-explain-this-double-negative-trick

Comment: @antonpug ok, the link you posted only show that I'm right. !! will never return true on undefined. Single ! convert any value to Boolean and apply the NOT operation to it, second ! will just apply one more NOT.

Answer (score 3):

`!!` is not an operator in itself; it is merely a way of using JavaScript's logical NOT (`!`) operator.

To convert `x` to a boolean, `!!x` works because when you negate a boolean twice, you get the original boolean, and `!x` converts `x` to a boolean before negating it.

Likewise, `!!!x` converts `x` to a boolean and negates it three times, which is equivalent to negating it only once. So you can use `!x` instead of `!!!x`.

Comment: This answer is perfect and very clear.

Answer (score 1):

> that's for "True" conditions.

No, it's for any value. `!!` will convert any value in it's equivalent Boolean value.

Why? Because the not operator simply returns the opposite Boolean value. So

```
0    // is falsy
!0   // -> true
!!0  // -> false

'foo'    // is truthy
!'foo'   // -> false
!!'foo'  // -> true
```

Any additional application will just toggle the value again. Thus `!!!` is equivalent to `!` and `!!!!` is equivalent to `!!` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolCheck = 0;
   boolCheck //0
  !boolCheck //true
 !!boolCheck //false
!!!boolCheck //true - again
```

Same thing here:

```
var boolCheck = 1;
   boolCheck //1
  !boolCheck //false
 !!boolCheck //true
!!!boolCheck //false - again
```

There is no reason to use this ( !!! ), it is a tautology. **!!** is useful when:

1. we need to have a Boolean value, when there are some results ( !!5 => true );
2. we need to shorten **false** with **!1** or **true** - **!0**.

   1. or to skip the wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

This answers your question perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/1561922

!!!x is probably inversing a boolean conversion !!x:

```
var myBool = Boolean("false");  // == true

var myBool = !!"false";  // == true
```

"Any string which isn't empty will evaluate to true"

So `!!!"false"; // == false`

This question is NOT a joke. [Node.js (downloaded 5 days ago) uses this in Assert.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10/lib/assert.js#L111-L113) for example:

```
function ok(value, message) {
  if (!!!value) fail(value, true, message, '==', assert.ok);
}
assert.ok = ok;
```

EDIT: I think they did it for code readability reasons out of habit, because [!value already suffices](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/5S5kv/1/).

EDIT: [Node changed it.](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/dc9acd4faeba1aade414bdd8da28f30b16773575) I have no idea why my version of Node.js that was downloaded 5 days ago is still with the !!!value instead of the !value in GitHub.

EDIT: [This is the reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741106/why-does-node-js-assert-js-use-value-in-their-code-what-purpose-does-it-ser?noredirect=1#comment-36498421).