# Why does Node.js' Assert.js use !!!value in their code? What purpose does it serve?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function ok(value, message) {
  if (!!!value) fail(value, true, message, '==', assert.ok);
}
assert.ok = ok;
```

`!!!value` basically means `not not not Boolean(value)` yes?

Say if `value = 9 > 1`, then it would mean: `not not not true`.

```
not true = false
not not true = true
not not not true = false
```

My brain hurts. Why don't they just use `!value` instead of `!!!value`?

Comment: Presumably, it is because it is very hard to overlook when reading the code.

Comment: Maybe because "they" started with with boolean conversion only (`!!`), then had to negate the condition later and lost track of the meaning of the code in-between?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt rather http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550294/what-does-the-syntax-mean-in-javascript

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Haha, that duplicate question has a -1 vote! Awesomesauce.

Comment: There's an issue on the project about this, [#5885](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/5885), that's already been resolved, [dc9acd4](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/dc9acd4faeba1aade414bdd8da28f30b16773575).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski If it has been [resolved already in July 2013 by bnoordhuis](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/dc9acd4)... why am I seeing it in my Node.js installation that I just downloaded and installed like 5 days ago?

Comment: @Geoyws Different branches. It's been resolved for 0.11, but [remains unchanged for 0.10](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10/lib/assert.js#L111-L113).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Wow man. Thanks, that's a sanity-saver. Could you write an answer please? Just so the community can benefit.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

!! is Cast or Convert the variable to Boolean and the additional ! inverts it.
I think you could do this if it's easier to read var invertedBool = !Boolean("false");

Comment: No, with `!!`, the first `!` casts to a boolean and inverts it and the second reverts it to its original truthiness value.

Comment: A single application of the `!` operator is enough to both convert the operand to a boolean and negate it. You don't have to explicitly invoke `Boolean()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You're right. http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/5S5kv/1/ Perhaps they just did it for readability out of habit. But indeed ! would suffice. Ah the programmer's life.

Answer (score 3):

`!value` and `!!!value` both do have the *same effect*.

But, they intenionally use `!!` to convert the potential 'truthy' or 'falsy' variable `value` to a boolean.

So it does makes sense to use `!!!` when using `value` as a negated boolean, so *developers can see that (in this case) `value` may only be 'truthy'*, e.g. a string and not `true`.

If in refactoring someone needs to set something to true and uses `value`, it may be set to a string. The `!!!` tells him to use `!!value`, if he expects `value` as a boolean.

Comment: R.E your second paragraph; it makes *more* sense to use a single `!`, as it has the *same* effect as `!!!`.

Comment: This utterly fails to address the question of why !!!value is different than !value, which it in fact isn't.

Comment: The Question wasnt *why !!!value is different than !value*. The question was why they did write it that way.

Comment: @Matt yes it has the same *effect*. But the triple `!` states that `value` does not necessarily has to be `true`.

Comment: @juk: I'm not sure what you mean. A single `!` does not require `value`` to be true either.

Comment: Well, I see the `!!!` as a simple warning to maintainers, that `value` could also be a `string`, `number`, or whatever and shall not to be expected to be a Boolean. Not specifically dangerous in asserts `ok` method, but in my eyes legitimate for a coding convention.

Answer (score 1):

The likely answer is either that they're using it to draw emphasis to the conversion or that some programmer just thought it was funny at some point -- there's absolutely no syntactical difference between `!x` and `!!!x` (or `!!!!!!!!!!!!!x` for that matter). After the first `!` which will convert the variable to a boolean,  you're just repeatedly adding the `not` operator to something. All that matters is whether it's negated an even or odd number of times.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly brain-pain inducing.

Normally, you would see something like the following
    var error_boolean = !!(error);

This is done to force "error_boolean" to either true or false.

My guess is this is a refactor bug w/ harmless consequences. Someone probably replaced something like `notValue` (which was double negated here), with `!value`. What does annotating that line of source tell you?

Or this is simply a way to garner attention at the line, its working on us so far.