# How to get content in square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get value is true in square brackets.
I cannot get option is true or false by getting value from square brackets.

For example i have ID :

```
values = content.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
$(this).closest(".myclass").myFn({
           postMe: values[0],
                    });
```

value[0] is the first value get from an ID (#myID) but It does not run. I put square brackets like:

```
<div id="myID">[true]</div>
```

But I put directly like :

```
values = content.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
$(this).closest(".myclass").myFn({
           postMe: true,
                    });
```

It runs ok. Say me solution for this issue. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) here like:

```
var result = content.test(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
$(this).closest(".myclass").myFn({
    postMe: result,
});
```

As **`test`** executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string and then returns *true* or *false* based on it.

While **`match`** only retrieve the matches (in the form of array) when matching a string against a *regular expression*.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying with your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Your regex returns a string, not a boolean. `value[0]` = `'true'`, not true.
You have to cast your string to a boolean first ([see this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)).
Your code could be looking like this

```
values = content.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);
$(this).closest(".myclass").myFn({
    Random : (values[0] === 'true'),
});
```