# Javascript String to Boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I'm using jQuery to check the value of the select box and the values are either `true` or `false` but when I go to select the value in the jquery it recognises it as a string.

Then I have to go change it to a Boolean for it to work in my `setOptions` I was wondering if it was possible to convert to Boolean without having to go through the process I've done below?

**html**

```
<select name="scalecontrol" id="scalecontrol">
    <option value="false">None</option>
    <option value="true" selected="selected">Standard</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#scalecontrol').change(function(){
    ao.scalecontrol = $(this).val();
    if (ao.scalecontrol == 'false'){
        ao.scalecontrol = false;
    } else {
        ao.scalecontrol = true;
    }
    map.setOptions({
        scaleControl:ao.scalecontrol
    });
});
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: I deleted my answer because a) it was overkill (thanks @musefan) and b) it's already been answered before

Comment: try this ao.scalecontrol = ($(this).val() === 'true');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `.val()` results in a string type then you have to work with that, however you can shorten your code to the following:

```
$('#scalecontrol').change(function(){
    ao.scalecontrol = $(this).val() == 'true';
    map.setOptions({
        scaleControl:ao.scalecontrol
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#scalecontrol').change(function(){
    map.setOptions({
        scaleControl: $(this).val() === "true"
    });
});
```