# Does the double-exclamation (!!) trick always produce true or false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, boolean

Pardon me asking (I'm coming from the world of C/C++)

I'm curious if the following line will always set `bResult` to be either `true` or `false` in JavaScript?

```
var bResult = !!someVariable;
```

Comment: Yes. The not operator (`!`) always returns a Boolean. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29

Comment: No, if the operand doesn't exist, youl'll get an error instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand used for converting anything to boolean type, same as

```
var bResult = Boolean(someVariable);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/3094153

Comment: It will also cause an error if `someVariable` was undefined.

Answer (score 1):

According to `ECMAScript Language Specification`,

> The production UnaryExpression : ! UnaryExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> Let oldValue be ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)).

In case of `var bResult = !!someVariable;`, the first logical **Not** operator is evaluated

```
oldvalue = !(ToBoolean(value of someVariable))
```

See the table below for how different datatypes are converted to to Boolean. So based on the type and value of 'someVariable' the conversion would take place.

```
Argument Type   Result
Undefined       false
Null            false
Boolean         The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
Number          The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.
String          The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
Object          true
```

> If oldValue is true, return false. Return true.

This completes evaluation of the first logical **NOT** operator,

`bResult = !(oldValue)` // the second logical **NOT** operator is evaluated again in the same manner and the result is obtained.

So the result depends on the data type and the value of 'somevariable', and it is not a trick.