# Javascript compare appended true/false value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my JS code as below;

```
var editable = isNameEditable(this.get("status"));
return "<div class='editableTxt' name='myNameFld' data-editable=" + editable + "'">" + this.get("name") + "</div>";
```

The function isNameEditable just returns boolean value (true/false)

I then append it to my div using data-editable attribute.

I use the above value for comparision later and use below code;

```
if ($(this).attr('data-editable'))
```

However, the appended value becomes a string ("true"/"false") and hence the above condition does not work as expected.

Is there any way by which I can append a boolean value, so that I do not have to change my comparison
i.e.

```
if ($(this).attr('data-editable'))
```

Comment: `var editable = isNameEditable(this.get("status")) || ''` ?

Answer (score 4):

String boolean values to boolean conversion methods are explained in this post:

[How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

For example, you can use

```
if(!!$(this).data('editable'))
```

to check if the div is editable.

Comment: `.data()` method will already convert it to boolean, anyway good point of using `.data()` method

Comment: I didn't know about that :/

Comment: so u mean i should update my condition to account for string true/false values

Comment: BTW, `$.data("string) = $.attr("data-string")`. You may need to update it yes.