# What is the Javascript comparison operator for Telerik grid's IsContainedIn FilterOperator

Tags: javascript, c#, enums, telerik-grid

I want to use the [`IsContainedIn`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/t_telerik_windows_data_filteroperator.htm) `FilterOperator` for [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) grid.

The following is the `FilterOperator` enum

```
public enum FilterOperator
{
    IsLessThan = 0,
    IsLessThanOrEqualTo = 1,
    IsEqualTo = 2,
    IsNotEqualTo = 3,
    IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo = 4,
    IsGreaterThan = 5,
    StartsWith = 6,
    EndsWith = 7,
    Contains = 8,
    IsContainedIn = 9,
    DoesNotContain = 10,
}
```

## Operator    Description

- `eq`  Is equal to
- `ne`  Is not equal to
- `gt`  Is greater than
- `ge`  Is greater than or equal to
- `lt`  Is less than
- `le`  Is less than or equal to

But I need Operator for IsContainedIn FilterOperator.

Comment: Per Telerik Documentaion [link](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/t_telerik_windows_data_filteroperator.htm) 
Telerik.Windows.Data.FilterOperator.IsContainedIn is a boolean variable, with values true or false. 

Based on the value returned(true, false in string or just a plain boolean), you might need to typecast it from string to javascript Boolean type to use it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: I am constructing filter object as below                           $filter.push({ field: 'columnName', operator: "eq", value: 'abc' });                                                    Same way I need to use IsContainedIn FilterOperator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation they don't have a specific one for IsContainedIn where you are trying to use it. Looks like behind the scenes for the server side version they just use contains and then change the left and right hand operands. That may not work for your client-side filter here.

See the documentation where they document the only ones they do actually have available.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter.operator

filter.operator String

The filter operator (comparison). The supported operators are: "eq" (equal to), "neq" (not equal to), "lt" (less than), "lte" (less than or equal to), "gt" (greater than), "gte" (greater than or equal to), "startswith", "endswith", "contains". The last three are supported only for string fields.