# Convert Any data types(String Number ...) to boolean without using Boolean() Method

Tags: javascript

Is there any way (except Boolean method) for converting any data types to boolean? This is an interview question and I didn't answer it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript) Or maybe one of the other of [today’s menu options](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+convert+boolean) …?

Comment: Not string all data types...

Comment: Well fell free to make the search term more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Two Logical NOT !!
```

Logical not always returns a `Boolean` value, regardless of the data type it’s
used on:

```
If the operand is an object, `false` is returned.
If the operand is an empty string, `true` is returned.
If the operand is a nonempty string, `false` is returned.
If the operand is the number 0, `true` is returned.
If the operand is any number other than 0 (including Infinity), `false` is returned.
If the operand is null, `true` is returned.
If the operand is NaN, `true` is returned.
If the operand is undefined, `true` is returned.
```

The logical NOT operator can also be used to convert a value into its Boolean equivalent. By using
two NOT operators in a row, you can effectively simulate the behavior of the Boolean() casting
function. The first NOT returns a Boolean value no matter what operand it is given. The second
NOT negates that Boolean value and so gives the true Boolean value of a variable. The end result is
the same as using the `Boolean()` function on a value

Answer (score 0):

The abstract operation that converts to a boolean is called [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2):

- Undefined: `false`
- Null: `false`
- Boolean: The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
- Number: The result is `false` if the argument is `+0`, `−0`, or `NaN`; otherwise the result is `true`.
- String: The result is `false` if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is `true`.
- Object: `true`.

However, this operation is internal and not available.

But there are some workaround to use it:

- [Logical NOT Operator ( ! )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9)

  ```
  !!variable;
  ```
- [Conditional Operator ( ? : )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12)

  ```
  variable ? true : false;
  ```
- [Boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.1.1)

  ```
  Boolean(variable)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Implicit:

```
!!variable;
```

Explicit:

```
variable ? true : false;
```