# How do I convert an attrs property to a boolean in angular?

Tags: angularjs

How do I convert `attrs.requireItems` to a boolean?

```
attrs.$observe("requireItems", function(){
    var val = attrs.requireItems;
    ngModel.$setValidity("require-items", !!val);
});
```

The possible values are all strings but can be "true" "false" "0" or "N" (where N is the length of an array).

The problem is when its `"0"` or `"false"` it returns true because its a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: Why isn't it more of a Javascript question rather than an AngularJs question?

Comment: I thought maybe angular had a way to do this. Seems a pretty common issue.