# localStorage and boolean 'string'

Tags: javascript, html, boolean, local-storage

Storing boolean value in localStorage, this value is converted to string.
Now trying to converting back this value from localStorage to boolean, i need to use `JSON.parse()` method, the more handy `!!` doesn't work.

Code sample:

```
var test = false;
localStorage['test'] = test;
console.log("JSON.parse returns: ", JSON.parse(localStorage['test']), "expected: ", test);
console.log("'!!' returns: ", !! localStorage['test'], "expected: ", test);
```

### -jsFiddle-

I'm quite confused why this behaviour. Any explaination?

PS: using getter/setter localStorage methods doesn't matter here, same result.

Comment: because `!!"false"===true`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Local storage stores strings , I'm afraid, whatever the input (if you feed it with an object, it will be converted automatically with its standard `toString()` method)... So you're doing `!! test` on a string, which is always `true`.

You should always use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` when dealing with what you store in [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Answer (score 5):

*Use* `JSON.stringify()` when save the object. As you know it will convert JavaScript value to a JSON string so when using `JSON.parse()` its converted back properly.

```
localStorage['test'] = JSON.stringify(test);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7qug487c/)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because any stored value in localstorage is a string.
So you've perofming `!!"false"` and `!!` is always `true` for non-empty string.
To be able to store non-string values in localStorage you have to always use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is simple with [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), where you can transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, **Boolean**, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'test', false );

localDataStorage.get( 'test' );   -->   false
```

All of the conversion work is done in the background for you: just set/get and go.