# !variable not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `javascript:` bookmarklet with the code

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = !document.body.contentEditable;
```

which should switch on and off an "editor" for the page (just for pranks on friends and such). But it does not acheive the desired outcome, nothing happens when I click the bookmark. Opening up the Javascript Console, I see that:

```
document.body.contentEditable
  "false"
!document.body.contentEditable
  false
```

Previously, I used `javascript:document.body.contentEditable = true;` and this makes the page editable but I cannot turn it off.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: type this in console when its enabled: `typeof document.body.contentEditable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deceze is correct here, I (somewhat stupidly) thought that because you do
`document.body.contentEditable = true;`
you could also do
`!document.body.contentEditable;`
but this is not correct.

In the end, I decided to use the property that is actually a boolean, [`isContentEditable`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_iscontenteditable.asp), like so:
`document.body.contentEditable = !document.body.isContentEditable;`

Answer (score 9):

Like you probably noticed in the JavaScript Console, `document.body.contentEditable` is a String, not a Boolean. You can do this instead:

```
document.body.contentEditable = !(document.body.contentEditable == "true");
```

or just

```
document.body.contentEditable = document.body.contentEditable != "true";
```

> The HTMLElement.contentEditable property is used to indicate whether
>   or not the element is editable. This enumerated attribute can have the
>   following values:
>
> - "true" indicates that the element is contenteditable.
> - "false" indicates that the element cannot be edited.
> - "inherit" indicates that the element inherits its parent's editable status.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.contentEditable` is a string value and JavaScript considers non-empty strings to be truthy.

```
!"" == true
!"a" == false
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `contentEditable` is a string, not a boolean. It can have the values `"true"`, `"false"` or `"inherit"` (therefore it can't be a simple boolean). A boolean inversion won't work. You need to explicitly assign one of these three strings.

Answer (score 0):

Is contentEditable a text input? So you need to parse the texto into boolean:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = !JSON.parse(document.body.contentEditable);
```