# Can't get the value of @Html.RadioButtonFor using Jquery, checked attribute not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using MVC 5, I have a radio button for a Boolean property on a Razor view, a simple yes or no selection, like so:

```
<td class="warning">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.HeartCondition)</td>
<td class="info">Yes @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HeartCondition, true, new { @class = "radio" })</td>
<td class="info">No @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.HeartCondition, false, new { @class = "radio"})</td>

<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btnnav" id="SaveParQ">Save & Next</a>
```

When I pass a true or false value to the view, the corresponding radio button is selected, and has the checked="checked" attribute.  I then want to save the value without having to reload the page, which I'm trying to do using jquery, and this is where the problem lies.  If I pass a true value to the view, the "yes" radio button is selected and has the checked attribute, but when I click the "no" radio button, the "no" button does get selected, but the checked attribute is still on the "yes" button, and doesn't change to the "no" button, which is what I thought it would've done.

My jquery looks like this:

```
//Save ParQ
$("body").on("click", "#SaveParQ", function (e) {
    preventDefaultAction(e);
    var url = GetUrlPath() + "/PreAssessment/SaveParQ";
    var parQId = $("#ParQId").val();
    var heartCondition = false;
    if ($("input[name='heartCondition']:checked").val()) {
        heartCondition = true;
    }

    var viewModel = new ParQViewModel(parQId, heartCondition);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success === true) {
                showFullScreenLoadMask(false);
                $("#ParQId").val(result.ParQId);
            }
        },
        error: function (responseText, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if my jquery is right, but if it is, it doesn't register me changing "yes" to "no", because the checked attribute stays on the original element.  Can anyone help with the right way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Your selector `input[name='heartCondition']:checked` must match the case of the model's property => change it to `HeartCondition`.

Comment: That is what I want, but whenever I click the radio button from "yes"(true) to "no"(false), the yes radio button still has the checked attribute, and the no button doesn't, so the jquery doesn't get the changed value, just the original value.

Comment: You can also just use `var heartCondition = $("input[name='HeartCondition']:checked").val();`

Comment: just checked it, and this actually worked, the jquery is getting the value perfectly now, thanks.  Post this as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following lines of code

```
var heartCondition = false;
if ($("input[name='heartCondition']:checked").val()) {
    heartCondition = true;
}
```

and replace with

```
var heartCondition = $("input[name='HeartCondition']:checked").val();
```

which will set the value to either `true` or `false` based on the selected radio button.

Comment: You probably want to make sure you [end up with a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript) or else `heartCondition !== false;`

Comment: @Liam, not really necessary - its being stringified and posted to a controller.

Comment: If you ask me to take the time to add an answer so that you can accept it, at least have the courtesy to do so.