# String to Boolean

Tags: javascript

I've read numerous examples converting from String to Boolean.

For example,

myString = (myString == "true");

But I'm unable to apply the logic to my code. Can someone help?

> CommonConfig.getFeatureFlags['analytics.demo'] returns "true" (Note
>   the "").(That's how backend returns it)

```
var FeatureFlag = _.extend(CommonConfig, {
    demoFeature: String == CommonConfig.getFeatureFlags['analytics.demo'], //either "true" or "false" but I want to make it to true or false
});
```

Question: I want to convert from String "true" to boolean. And pass true or false based upon!

Can someone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Why are you comparing to `String`?! You want to compare to `"true"`!

Comment: use strict comparison with `===`

Comment: `(yourString === "true")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it:

```
var FeatureFlag = _.extend(CommonConfig, {
    demoFeature: "true" == CommonConfig.getFeatureFlags['analytics.demo'], 
});
```

Comment: why does it solve the problem?

Comment: @Nina Why *doesn't* it?!

Comment: @deceze, i don't know. i don't know how to program. i'm just learning.

Comment: @Nina Riiiiiight.... You may have been overlooking that OP is comparing to `String`, which is plain nonsense...?