# In JavaScript when verifying true condition

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript when verifying true condition

Below

```
if(variablename=='true')
```

is working but

```
if(variablename==true)
```

is not working. Any reasons for this?  Is it specific to some browsers?

Comment: What is `variablename` here?

Comment: 'true' !== true, 'true' is a string not a Boolean and shouldn't be used to check truthiness.

Comment: 'true' and true are two different thing - one is string and another is boolean.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality.

Answer (score -1):

Strings and booleans aren't the same thing at all. Non-empty strings are all equivalent to true ([How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)). You need to determine what the type of variablename is and implement the appropriate comparison.

The difference between 'true' and true is similar to the differences between '3' and 3, or 3.0 and 3. In many cases they will "work". Using these assumptions and implicit coercions is not safe and will eventually cause trouble.

Languages such as JavaScript that support implicit coercions give you plenty of rope. It's up to you to not hang yourself with it.

Comment: How are `3.0` and `3` different? And no, the difference between `'3'` and `3` is **not** similar to the difference between `'true'` and `true`. Nor is it correct to say that "non-empty strings are all equivalent to true". I guess what you meant to say is that "non-empty strings are considered true in a boolean context (in other words, 'truthy')".

Comment: I meant that they are different in some languages.