# How to convert string into boolean?

Tags: javascript, html

I read out a data-attibute, then I want to convert the string "true" into a boolean. At the moment I have to do a comparison in the javascript, is there a better way to do it? I don't know how to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

HTML

```
<div data-nav='{ "nav": "true"}'>
```

JS

```
    var data = JSON.parse($nav.attr('data-nav').toString());
    data.nav = (data.nav === "true") ? true : false;
```

Comment: Personally I would do it the way you did: `data.nav = (data.nav === "true") ? true : false; `

Comment: ...except that the `? true : false` part is totally redundant.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<div id='test' data-nav='true'>


var truefalse = $('#test').data('nav');
```

.data should be able to evaluate it as boolean

here is an example in JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/lismore/hx3gLvgw/