# jQuery cookie sets boolean value as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm working with a cookie, setting other code varibles using the value of the cookie.

I have defined data about the default state of the cookie as so:

```
const Cookie = {
  config: {
    name: 'Test_Cookie',
    expire: 1,
    value: true,
  },
...
}
```

When criteria are met, the cookie gets set for the first time, using `this.config.value` to set the value of the cookie to `true`:

```
  setCookie: function () {
    if (!this.isCookieSet()) {
      $.cookie(this.config.name, this.config.value, this.config.expire);
    }
  },
```

However, I am finding when I return the cookie value in the code I get `"true"` back as a string rather than just `true`. For example (name changed in above example for simplicity):

[image]

If I try to do a comparison on the `value` of the cookie, and use `=== true` I get a false result. If I do `=== "true"` then I get a true result:

```
showStuff = $.cookie('Test_Cookie') === "true"; // showStuff = true;
```

OR

```
showStuff = $.cookie('Test_Cookie') === true; // showStuff = false;
```

**Why does the variable type of the cookie value change when set?**

Comment: Cookies are really just strings. Saving a boolean as a cookie will in fact make it a string. The same will happen for any value you save as a cookie.

Comment: FYI, the same goes for `localstorage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are strings. You'll need to convert the cookie value to the type you want. The boolean values are being saved as true or false because that's the string representation of a boolean.

You can use the following.

`var myBool = Boolean($.cookie('Test_Cookie'));`

or

`var myBool = ($.cookie('Test_Cookie') === "true");`

**EDIT**
As suggested in the first comment by @DelightedD0D:

You could also try -  `$.cookie('Test_Cookie') === "true"`

Comment: Yeah, but be careful, this could act unexpectedly, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/1376624). Pobably best just to check for   `$.cookie('Test_Cookie') === "true"`

Comment: Don't use Boolean() in this case because:
`Boolean('false') === true`

Answer (score 2):

For future readers: You can check against the string value as noted in other answers or convert it to a Boolean value for greater flexibility.

```
function stringToBoolean(string) {
  switch(string.toLowerCase()) {
    case "false": case "no": case "0": case "": return false;
    default: return true;
  }
}

const isTrue = stringToBoolean("true");
const isFalse = !isTrue;
```

**ref:** [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414175/2134533)