# Typescript string to boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert a string to boolean. There are several ways of doing it 
one way is

```
let input = "true";
let boolVar = (input === 'true');
```

The problem here is that I have to validate input if it is true or false. Instead of validating first input and then do the conversion is there any more elegant way?
In .NET we have `bool.TryParse` which returns false if the string is not valid. Is there any equivalent in typescript?

Comment: I don't know about .NET, but if `bool.TryParse` returns `false` on "invalid" strings… isn't that the same as *returning `true` if string is `"true"` else `false`*…? Exactly what you're doing already?

Comment: If someone types "John" John is not a valid bool. That does not mean it is false.

Comment: But isn't that what the .NET thing you described does? I pass it "John", that's not valid, it returns false. I still don't see the difference.

Comment: The `tryParse` in .NET returns both the validness AND the result. (The second parameter is a refference that will be set to the actual outcome, while it returns whether it successfully parsed it or not.)

Comment: @Ivar So it returns `false` and `false`? That makes more sense. And such a thing is not built into Javascript.

Comment: @deceze You are correct.

Comment: You can do `JSON.parse(string)` and if it throws an exception you can infer it is not valid.

Comment: not sure there really is anything better than this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript?rq=1 .

Comment: @csm_dev as Ivar described .NET returns both the validness AND the result.

Answer (score 26):

You can do something like this where you can have three states. `undefined` indicates that the string is not parseable as boolean:

```
function convertToBoolean(input: string): boolean | undefined {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(input.toLowerCase());
    }
    catch (e) {
        return undefined;
    }
}

console.log(convertToBoolean("true")); // true
console.log(convertToBoolean("false")); // false
console.log(convertToBoolean("True")); // true
console.log(convertToBoolean("False")); // false
console.log(convertToBoolean("invalid")); // undefined
```

Comment: I was looking for a builtin function of doing this but it seems that there isn't!

Comment: `JSON.parse` is the closest thing you will come to a built-in way to do this.

Comment: It doesn't work if string is in capital. e.g., "False". Therefore, JSON.parse(input) should be JSON.parse(input.toLowerCase())

Answer (score 6):

Returns `true` for `1`, `'1'`, `true`, `'true'` *(case-insensitive)* . Otherwise `false`

```
function primitiveToBoolean(value: string | number | boolean | null | undefined): boolean {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.toLowerCase() === 'true' || !!+value;  // here we parse to number first
  }

  return !!value;
}
```

Here is Unit test:

```
describe('primitiveToBoolean', () => {
  it('should be true if its 1 / "1" or "true"', () => {
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(1)).toBe(true);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('1')).toBe(true);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('true')).toBe(true);
  });
  it('should be false if its 0 / "0" or "false"', () => {
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(0)).toBe(false);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('0')).toBe(false);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('false')).toBe(false);
  });
  it('should be false if its null or undefined', () => {
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(null)).toBe(false);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(undefined)).toBe(false);
  });
  it('should pass through booleans - useful for undefined checks', () => {
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(true)).toBe(true);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean(false)).toBe(false);
  });
    it('should be case insensitive', () => {
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('true')).toBe(true);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('True')).toBe(true);
    expect(primitiveToBoolean('TRUE')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

[TypeScript Recipe: Elegant Parse Boolean (ref. to original post)](https://bloomlab.blogspot.com/2018/06/typescript-recipe-elegant-parse-boolean.html)

Answer (score 5):

You could also use an array of valid values:

```js
const toBoolean = (value: string | number | boolean): boolean => 
    [true, 'true', 'True', 'TRUE', '1', 1].includes(value);
```

Or you could use a switch statement as does [in this answer to a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017891/753279).

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have a string as input I suggest the following. It can be the case when retrieving an environment variable for example with `process.env` in Node

```
function toBoolean(value?: string): boolean {
  if (!value) {
    //Could also throw an exception up to you
    return false
  }

  switch (value.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
    case 'true':
    case '1':
    case 'on':
    case 'yes':
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-shamir-738g5?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version,

```
function parseBoolean(value?: string | number | boolean | null) {
    value = value?.toString().toLowerCase();
    return value === 'true' || value === '1';
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I suggest that you want boolVar to be true for input equals true and input equals "true" (same for false) else it should be false.

```
let input = readSomeInput(); // true,"true",false,"false", {}, ...
let boolVar = makeBoolWhateverItIs(input);

function makeBoolWhateverItIs(input) {
    if (typeof input == "boolean") {
       return input;
    } else if typeof input == "string" {
       return input == "true";  
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `Boolean(input)` will always return true as long as the string is not empty. So you are basically just doing `let boolVar = (input === 'true')`, which is the question in the first place. And even if it would work the way you expect, then still it doesn't make a difference between false and a non-boolean string.

Comment: Thats not true because Boolean("someOtherString") will return false, Boolean({}) will return false. So if your not sure that your input is a string (let could be any type) this is a good solution. true === "true" will also be false so you have to ensure that the type of input ist String but its let, so it could be everything.

Comment: `Boolean("someOtherString")` will be true. [Try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/gdp0vLvc/). From the question I understand that the input will always be a string. And as I said, even if you would be right, than it still doesn't separately check if the parse fails or not.

Comment: Also `Boolean({})` will return true. And `true == 'true'` will be false as well.

Comment: You are right this does not make any sense to me but your right.