# Make/ Create checkbox component in react native

Tags: button, checkbox, react-native, state, checked

I have been facing some issues with the native base checkbox and AsynStorage. In fact, AsynStorage only accepts strings by default BUT can store boolean variables also, I tried to use that method but I get a string stored every time. 
While the checkbox does only accept boolean variables and throws a warning if I  tried to use a string and it does not show the previous state of the checkbox (checked or not ). 
So, I decided to make my own checkbox using TouchbleOpacity .. So do you guys have any idea how to make it ? 
Here is the result i want to achieve: [image]

So, the purpose is to make a checkbox settings page that controls the style of a text in another page and to get the checkbox as left the previous time, for an example : if I check it , I change the page and go back again to the settings page , I need to find it checked (indicating the previous state)
The code is 
in the settings page :

```
toggleStatus() {
        this.setState({
            status: !this.state.status
        });
        AsyncStorage.setItem("myCheckbox",JSON.stringify(this.state.status));
    }
// to get the previous status stored in the AsyncStorage 
componentWillMount(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox').then((value) => {
            this.setState({
                status: value
            });
            if (this.state.status == "false") {
                this.setState({
                    check: false
                });
            }
            else if (this.state.status == "true") {
                this.setState({
                    check: true
                });
            }
            if (this.state.status == null) {
                this.setState({
                    check: false
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
render {
return(
 ...

                            <CheckBox
                                onPress={() => { this.toggleStatus() }
                                checked={ this.state.check }/>

)}
```

In other page :

```
componentDidMount(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox').then((value) => {
            JSON.parse(value)
            this.setState({
                status: value
            });

        });

    }
```

This code change the status after **TWO** clicks and I don't know why and i get this weird output in the console, every time I click the checkbox [image]

Comment: I think it may be better to have a look at the way you store/retrieve data from AsyncStorage, rather than re-inventing the wheel for the check box. I would store data through `JSON.stringify(myVal)`, and retrieve with `JSON.parse(fromStorage)` - that way you can store complex objects and maintain types.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [AsyncStorage documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html), you can see that, in fact, the method getItem() will always return a string (inside the promise).

For the problem with the AsyncStorage you should consider trying to parse this string returned to a boolean using [this method explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript) and then use this parsed value inside the native base checkbox.

But if you want to do your own component, try doing something like this:

```
export default class Checkbox extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { checked: false }
    }

    render(){
        return(
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{
            this.setState({ checked : !this.state.checked });
        }}    
        >
            <Image source={this.state.checked ? require('checkedImagePath') : require('uncheckedImagePath')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

You will need to set some style to this image to configure it the way you want.

-- Based on your edition:

I can't see nothing wrong on your toggleStatus() method in settings page, but try changing your componentWillMount() to this:

```
componentWillMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('myCheckbox').then((value) => {
        if (value != null){
            this.setState({
                check: (value == 'true')
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

However in the other page the line you do JSON.parse(value) is doing nothing, once you are not storing the result anywhere.

Comment: hey .. thank you actually i did to store the status as a string (which i did) and then to convert it to string ..BUT it's nit working and I don't know why .. I also tried your second solution and it's not changing the status instantly and it always goes back to the checked picture...Please check my edit in the question to see what i tried .