# How does bool works in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on that piece of code which doesn't behave as I expected.
Especially conditions.
In console log I see that objekt.teamA is false, teamA is false, objekt.teamB is true, teamB is true but 1st condition is accepted without any reason.

Could anybody tell me why is that so?

```
function wsConnect() 
            {
                var objekt = 
                {
                    teamA: document.getElementById('teamA').value,
                    teamB: document.getElementById('teamB').value
                };
                console.log("connect",wsUri);
                ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
                ws.onmessage = function(msg) 
                {
                    obj = JSON.parse(msg.data);
                    lightsAv = obj.lights;
                    doorsAv = obj.doors;
                    electricAv = obj.electric;
                    teamA = obj.teamA;
                    teamB = obj.teamB;
                    console.log(objekt.teamA + " " + teamA + " " + objekt.teamB + " " + teamB);
                    //objekt.teamA is false, teamA is false, objekt.teamB is true, teamB is true
                    if(objekt.teamA && !teamA)
                    {
                        console.log("1st condition");
                    }
                    if(objekt.teamB && !teamB)
                    {
                        console.log("2nd condition");
                    }
                }
                ws.onopen = function() 
                {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "connected";
                    console.log("connected");
                }
                ws.onclose = function() 
                {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "not connected";
                    setTimeout(wsConnect,3000);
                }
            }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's likely that `teamA` and `teamB` are not booleans. Can you show a [mcve] of your HTML as well?

Comment: `value` of an `<input>` is string, not boolean

Comment: In order to check the type do `console.log( typeof teamA )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: if(objekt.teamA && !teamA) is always equal to true because objekt.teamA is a string and you are comapring a string with boolean true.

Comment: @abhishekkhandait — No. They are testing the string for truthiness. That's not quote the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your claim:

> objekt.teamA is false, teamA is false

Your code:

> ```
> var objekt = 
> {
>     teamA: document.getElementById('teamA').value,
>     teamB: document.getElementById('teamB').value
> };
> ```

The value of `objekt.teamA` comes from the value property of a form control. This will **always be a string**.

So it is not `false`, it is `"false"`.

Strings of non-zero length are **truthy**.

```js
if ("false") {
    console.log("a true value")
}
```

You can test for the value explicitly:

```js
var myVar = "false";

if (myVar !== "false") {
   console.log("It is true");
} else {
   console.log("It is false");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are checking if the variable has a truthy value or not. By using,

`if( value ) {
 }`

This will evaluate to true if value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

To compare boolean value, you can use -

`if(varA === false && varB === true){
 }`