# Typescript with Angular 2 issue on boolean

Tags: angular

I'm facing a strange issue while filling a model from a API result.

My model looks like this:

```
import {Company} from './../api/odata/data/Company';

export class MyModel {
...
isEnabled = false;
....
    constructor(data: Company= null) {
        try {
            this.isEnabled = !data.isDisabled;
            ...
        }
        ...
}
```

When I fill the data model, if data.isDisabled equals false, this.isEnabled should be true, but it's returning false...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.isDisabled` is a string buddy. You could convert it to a boolean in multiple ways. But I am curious where the data came from in the first place.

If there is no way to ensure `data.isDisabled` comes as a boolean you could do two things.

1- Check what the strings value is and based on that return a boolean.

```
this.isEnabled = data.isDisabled === 'true' ? false : true
```

2- Or use eval, which I would not recommend

```
this.isEnabled = eval(data.isDisabled);
```

3- Backwards compatible solution, best of all three

This will even work if isDisabled is an actual boolean.

```
this.isEnabled = !JSON.parse(data.isDisabled);
```

See more on string to boolean conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i get a "Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '"true"'." when i try your first solution, and in the Company oData class, isDisabled is declared as boolean

Comment: The type definition of `isDisabled` is clearly wrong, otherwise the javascript debugger wouldn't be showing you a `string` How about fixing that ? :D

Comment: thanks, after changing it, it fixed the issue, I will ask the API dev to change this, it's not normal to return a string for a boolean value

Comment: @MarcElBichon For a more backwards solution that will work with the newly changed API. Check my updated answer :)