# What are intrinsic types in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have recently came across the term *intrinsic (data) types* in the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript) related to Javascript, but it was not clearly conveyed what is meant by this term.

So the question is. What are the *intrinsic (data) types* in Javascript?

Comment: More context would help, like a quote from the article…

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=intrinsic+javascript

Comment: @str This very question is the third result... oh, Ouroboros!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Intrinsic" is the way some authors refer to what other authors call "built-in". So, those data types/objects/classes are always there regardless of what environment you're running in.

E.g.:

> JavaScript provides intrinsic ***(or "built-in")*** objects. They are the `Array`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `Error`, `Function`, `Global`, `JSON`, `Math`, `Number`, `Object`, `RegExp`, and `String` objects.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/intrinsic-objects-javascript

Comment: However, those intrinsics are not data types.

Comment: Perhaps the specific article OP read was referring to *built-in strings, numbers* etc. The word "intrinsic" should have the same meaning though.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. But until the OP provides a quote or link to the article, I'll vote to close.

Comment: @deceze And by "environment" you mean "programming language"?

Comment: @Eduard No, I mean *runtime environment*, e.g. browser vs. node.js vs. embedded in some system. As long as it's *Javascript*, these "intrinsic"/"built-in" objects/types/whatever should always be available.

Comment: @deceze Thank you!