# Angular js convert string property to boolean inside json object

Tags: javascript

i'm working with angular js and i have the following array that contains many json object , each objects has the property "isSingle" which contains "true" or "false" , my issue is how to convert this property to boolean true or false :

```
[
    {
      "noFolder": "AW343",
      "type": "T7",
      "creationDate": "22/05/2017",
      "isSingle": "true"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "AW35",
      "type": "T34",
      "creationDate": "09/05/2017",
      "isSingle": "false"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "ASW3",
      "type": "T3",
      "creationDate": "05/07/2017",
      "isSingle": "true"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "BG5",
      "type": "T1",
      "creationDate": "22/12/2018",
      "isSingle": "false"
    }

]
```

my desired result is to have objects like :

```
  {
      "noFolder": "ASW3",
      "type": "T3",
      "creationDate": "05/07/2017",
      "isSingle": true
    }
```

do you have any idea about how to change the type of the property isSingle to bbolean. i'm using angularjs...

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: If you are using angular, shouldn't you be using Typescript instead of Javascript ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: Would it not be better to tackle the problem at the server API and have it return valid JSON for boolean values like `"{...,"isSingle":true}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Iterate over the array and replace the value as per your requirement like this -

```
var obj = [
    {
      "noFolder": "AW343",
      "type": "T7",
      "creationDate": "22/05/2017",
      "isSingle": "true"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "AW35",
      "type": "T34",
      "creationDate": "09/05/2017",
      "isSingle": "false"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "ASW3",
      "type": "T3",
      "creationDate": "05/07/2017",
      "isSingle": "true"
    },
    {
      "noFolder": "BG5",
      "type": "T1",
      "creationDate": "22/12/2018",
      "isSingle": "false"
    }

]

obj.map((e) => {
    e.isSingle == "true" ? e.isSingle = true : e.isSingle = false
});
```

Comment: @str I tried it on my console, is there any error in this code ?

Comment: Yes, Agree with your point. and yes it modifies original object

Answer (score 4):

Simple loop through the objects to convert string to bool:

```
yourArray.forEach(x => x.isSingle = x.isSingle === 'true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce method.

```
let updated_array = array.reduce(function(acc, elem) {
    acc.push(Object.assign({}, elem, { isSingle: (elem['isSingle'] == true ? true : false) }));
    return acc;
}, []);
```