# How do I set a boolean in parameter types for Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

Cucumber allows you to pass int, string, floats as parameter types, is there a way to do it with Booleans?

```
Given('the property {string} is set to {string}', function (path, value) {
    this.requestBody = this.requestBody || {};
    _.set(this.requestBody, path, value);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no, but I believe you'll find what you need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript).

There are multiple way to achieve this and most of them require you to parse a value to boolean inside the Given step. I believe in your case is the `value`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this neatly by defining a [custom parameter type](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#custom-parameter-types) for boolean, which will allow you to use {boolean} in your step expression in the same way as {string}, {float} etc.

step definition file

```
const { defineParameterType, Given } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");

defineParameterType({
  name: "boolean",
  regexp: /true|false/,
  transformer: (s) => s === "true" ? true : false
});

Given("the property {string} is set to {boolean}", function (path, value) {
  console.log(typeof value); // "boolean"
});
```

feature file

```
Given the property "theProp" is set to true
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: Good one, was really helpul