# If condition always executes

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to condition the execution of an if statement based on a Boolean value in an object in my DB.
For some reason it always executes. I am new to TypeScript so I might be getting something basic wrong.

This is my code:

```
exports.newCommunity = functions.firestore.document('communities/{communityID}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const community = snap.data();
    if (community !== undefined) {
        if (community.public == true) {
            return createCommunityInAlgolia(community);
        } else {
            return null;
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    };
});
```

I tried also having this as the if statement `(community.public === true)` or even simply this `(community.public)` (as the value is a Boolean). But it always executes.
I can't find any other reason in my code for this function to execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the possible return values for `snap.data()`?

Comment: Code looks correct. Looks like the problem in the data `community.public` (is always true)

Comment: maybe you're storing `community.public` as `string` representation of boolean values (e.g. "true", "false")

Comment: Please post possible values of `community` or just `community.public`

Comment: @JordiNebot `snap.data()` is always just documentData which is a map, or null. But I made the check first so I know it's not null, plus the following function uses that data with no problem so the data must be alright

Comment: @IhorSakaylyuk I can see in the DB it is false. But I agree it looks like this would be the problem but it's not I tried to do `if (community.public as Boolean)` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe you have your false in the DB as a string and not as a boolean. Keep in mind that `'false'` is a truthy value. Take a look at [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: Please add `console.log(typeof community.public)` and paste here what is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if there is data in the snapshot (which there will always be in an onCreate trigger), then check data inside that, this is better:

```
const community = snap.data();
if (community && community.public) {
    // your code
}
```