# Angular 7: Checkbox is checked with [(ngModel)] on ngoninit method

Tags: angular, angular7

I am calling the function below into ngoninit and binding a checkbox value with ngmodel. Here the problem is that the default checkbox is coming back as checked. I don't get where I am wrong.

Json format: `[{subproducts:[{checked:true}}]]`

```
<label for="checkbox" class="checkbox">  
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value=" 
  {{newsubProduct[0].product}}" [(ngModel)]="newsubProduct[0].checked" [ngModelOptions]="
  {standalone: true}" /> <i class="skin"></i><span> 
  {{ newsubProduct[0].product }}</span>
</label>

listproduct() {
this.Service.getData("some api").subscribe((d) => {
        let mydata = d;
        this.result = mydata;
        this.selProducts = this.result;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selProducts.length; i++) {
            let p1 = this.selProducts[i].subProducts.filter(p => p.checked);
            if (!_.isEmpty(p1)) {
                let p2 = p1.filter(p => {
                    if (p.checked) {
                        var checked = p.checked;
                        var product = p.backEndName;
                        this.newsubProduct.push({
                            checked: checked,
                            product: product
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    },
    err => {
        this.result = err;
    });}
```

The problem is that the checkbox is checked, I expect it to be unchecked.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: checkbox is coming as checked by default...

Comment: checkbox value should take from api as false or true which is not happening...

Comment: The json format that you shared is the one that is coming from api?

Comment: [ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "subProducts":[ 
         { 
            "id":100,
            "checked":"false",
            "backEndName":"DDA"
            
         }
      ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see from your comment, that your data looks like:

```ts
[ { "id":1, "subProducts":[ { "id":100, "checked":"false", "backEndName":"DDA" } ] } ]
```

So what we are seeing is that your get **string** value, not boolean. If you have access to the api, I would suggest that make the change there to return an actual boolean, not a string value. But if you can't do that change, you need to give the checkbox the boolean value. That can be done like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/7741865).

So make the following change:

```ts
this.newsubProduct.push({
  checked: (checked === 'true'),
  product: product
});
```

Now it should work: **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfxjmp)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. it's working fine.

Comment: Great, glad I could help! :)