# Proper way of getting boolean from option value for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, getelementbyid

This is my html:

```
<select id="popularCategorySelectID">
    <option id="1" value="false" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option id="2" value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
var popularCategorySelectElement = document.getElementById("popularCategorySelectID");
var popularCategorySelectElementValue = Boolean(popularCategorySelectElement.options[popularCategorySelectElement.selectedIndex].text);
```

I want to get the `Boolean` value like `true` or `false` here in `popularCategorySelectElementValue`. With the above code I am always getting `true`. I have tried with `[ngValue]="true"` but the result is same `true`.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, you're selecting the text inside each option.  So you're selecting "No" or "Yes" which have no direct relation to a boolean value.  Also, any non-empty string using Boolean() will return true.

Comment: You could make a function which checks the value Yes or No and returns a boolean.

Comment: I think you can find the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let bool = document.querySelector('#popularCategorySelectID').value === "true" ? true : false
```

Or even simply:

```
// this will return true if the conditional is true 
let bool = document.querySelector('#popularCategorySelectID').value === "true"
```

You could get a boolean value as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

```
document.getElementById("popularCategorySelectID").value
```

Comment: It would return a string. Mate wants a bool value.

Comment: Hello @AngeloSchulerPiletti, the idea behind my answer is to show him how to get the value using the ID. The other answer explains how to get a bool rather than a string. Cheers mate!