# Why JQuery (!) not assignment returning only false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and have a lot of boolean fields. I want these fields to return boolean value(1 or 0). I don't know if its an embarrassing question but I cant change the value of the input by not `(!)` assignment in jQuery. It works for 2 clicks and after that it always returns `false`. In first click since the value of the hidden input is empty it returns `true`, on second click it returns `false` as `!true=false`. After that on all the clicks it only returns `false`.

**My Html**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Required?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="form-control required_field">
  <input type="hidden" name="field_required[]" value="">
</div>
```

**My Jquery**

```
$('div').on('click', '.required_field', function() {
  let v = !($(this).siblings('input').val());
  $(this).siblings('input').val(v);
  console.log($(this).siblings('input').val());
});
```

It works with ternary operators and `if else`, if I compare with values as:

```
$('.div').on('click','.required_field',function(){
     $(this).siblings('input').val(($(this).siblings('input').val()==1)?0:1);
     console.log($(this).siblings('input').val());
});
```

Or

```
$('.up-field-sec').on('click','.required_field',function(){
        let v = $(this).siblings('input').val();
        $(this).siblings('input').val((!$(this).siblings('input').val() || v==0)?1:0);
        console.log($(this).siblings('input').val());
    });
```

I find it very strange how can it be `!false = false` ?? What am I missing here? This is bugging me. I would be very glad if anyone can explain this to me. Thank you in advance.

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/py9j8qtd/2/) of the code.

Comment: HTML inputs return strings, and due to JS's loose types `!"0"` is still `false`

Comment: `x == 1` is not quite the same as `!x`

Comment: Are you sure you want to invert value? Maybe `!!x`?

Comment: You are actually evaluating !"false" which turns into !true which results in false

Comment: @nip thank you and ty all I understand the problem.

Comment: Does this mean we cannot invert the boolean values(true or false) taken from input field's value using `!` like the way we do  in `PHP` and other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me, you guys rock!

I did some digging and this is the conclusion I came up to:

Here what is happeing in the code above. Every time when value of the input is taken from a `HTML` element it is a string. The value in the first click will be an empty string and `(!'')` (just like if empty is false !empty is true) will be `true` which is same as `!0` which is true.  In second click the value of the input will be `"true"` (a string) and `!'true'` (value is not empty so it will return false) is false. Till then everything looks perfect. After this every other clicks will return `false` string value `not(!) operator` will return false because the value is not empty.

To understand better

```
//first click
console.log('first click');
let v = '';
console.log('!v is: '+!v);
console.log('typeof !v is: '+typeof(!v));
console.log(!v);
v = !v;

//second click
console.log('Second click');
v='true';
console.log('!v is: '+!v);
console.log('typeof !v is: '+typeof(!v));
console.log(!v);

//third click
console.log('Third click');
v='false';
console.log('!v is: '+!v);
console.log('typeof !v is: '+typeof(!v));
console.log(!v);

//Fourth click
console.log('Fourth click');
v='false';
console.log('!v is: '+!v);
console.log('typeof !v is: '+typeof(!v));
console.log(!v);
```

To overcome this and preserve the boolean value:

```
$('div').on('click', '.required_field', function() {
  let v = !($(this).siblings('input').val()==='true');
  $(this).siblings('input').val(v);
  console.log($(this).siblings('input').val());
});
```

I got help from:
[How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/4919258)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because any non-empty string coerces to true, even if it contains the word `"false"`, or the number `"0"`. As such, `!"false"` is always `false`.

To fix this you need to use `!!`. The right `!` converts the string to a boolean and the left `!` operator inverts that result.

```js
$('div').on('click', '.required_field', function() {
  let v = !!$(this).siblings('input').val();    
  $(this).siblings('input').val(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label>Required?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" class="form-control required_field">
  <input type="hidden" name="field_required[]" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank yo for the solution but I am curious why `!true` returned `false` on the second click?

Comment: On the first click the value was an empty string, which coerces to `false` correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the clearification. I understand the problem.

Comment: now after adding `!!` it remains true after the second click.

Comment: Indeed. If all you're trying to do is store the boolean state of the `checked` flag in the textbox (which itself is a little redundant), just use the `checked` property directly: `$(this).siblings('input').val(this.checked);`

Comment: I wanted to send the checked propertery as a definite boolean values (0,1) so that I can mass assign the database according to value without thinking much about filtering the data. I have been using `$(this).siblings('input').val((!v || v==0)?1:0);` for the expected result. But I was only curious about why the value from an input definite (true, flase) can't be inverted using not`(!)` operator like many other languages with JQuery val() property. One thing is sure that the val property is fetching the value as "true", "false". For integer there is `parseInt` but for boolean  there isnt such.