# convert string value from input to boolean

Tags: string, input, next.js, boolean

there is my code

I want to get value in boolean. but value always in string

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Object.keys(formData).length == 0)
      return console.log("Don't Have Form Data");
    console.log(formData);
    axios.post(url, formData);
  };
```

```
<div className="items-center ">
        <label>Status</label>
        <div className="form-check">
          <input
            type="radio"
            onChange={setFormData}
            value="true"
            id="radioDefault1"
            name="status"
            className="form-check-input appearance-none rounded-full h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white checked:bg-green-500 checked:border-green-500 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer"
          ></input>
          <label htmlFor="radioDefault1" className="inline-block text-gray-600">
            Active
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
          <input
            type="radio"
            onChange={setFormData}
            value="false"
            id="radioDefault2"
            name="status"
            className="form-check-input appearance-none rounded-full h-4 w-4 border border-gray-300 bg-white checked:bg-green-500 checked:border-green-500 focus:outline-none transition duration-200 mt-1 align-top bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-contain float-left mr-2 cursor-pointer"
          ></input>
          <label htmlFor="radioDefault2" className="inline-block text-gray-600">
            Inactive
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

my value always show string "true" or "false"

how to convert this value to boolean

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the operator (===) which doesn't do any type conversion. Consider the snippet below hope it helps. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264037/10766490) explains more

```js
const data1 = "true"
const data2 = "false"
const data3 = "True"

const myBool = (value) => {
  if (value === "true") return true
  else if (value === "false") return false
  else return undefined
}

console.log(myBool(data1)) //true
console.log(myBool(data2)) //false
console.log(myBool(data3)) //undefined
```