# convert to bool if "false" or "true", leave string otherwise

Tags: javascript

What is the most efficient one-liner (if possible) for:

```
if (val == "true"){
 value = true;
}
else if (val == "false"){
 value = false;
}
else {
 value = val;
}
```

val is string.

Comment: `value = JSON.parse(val)`?

Comment: What are the other possible values of `val`?

Comment: does it help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in one line with ternary operator :

`value = val == "true" ? true : (val == "false" ? false : val);`

Comment: You sure can, but is it really more clear that OP's initial version? Easier to maintain and read? I'd prefer OP's version.

Comment: He asked for a one line. This is one. And very easy to read and understand

Answer (score 0):

```js
let val = 'false';

val = {'true': true, 'false': false, [val]:val}[val]

console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with null colalescing with the given string.

```js
const
    bOrS = v => ({ true: true, false: false }[v] ?? v);

console.log(bOrS('true'), typeof bOrS('true'));
console.log(bOrS('false'), typeof bOrS('false'));
console.log(bOrS('foo'), typeof bOrS('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just a `&&` and a `||`:

`value = val == "true" || val != "false" && val;`

but will you still understand it when you read it in a month or two?

```js
const toBool = val => val == "true" || val != "false" && val;

["true", "false", "something", ""].forEach(val => {
  const value = toBool(val);
  console.log({ val, value, type: typeof value });
});
```